# What are the available "documentclass" types and their uses?

Tags: document-classes, big-list

Some of the available classes of documents in LaTeX are well known and widely used, such as the [`article`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/classes.pdf) and `beamer` classes, while others are not so well known, such as the [`standalone`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452/how-can-i-create-a-pdf-document-exactly-as-big-as-my-tikz-picture/514#514) class.

I found [this figure](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Document_classes) (edit: transcribed)

> **`article`** for articles in scientific journals, presentations, short reports, program documentation, invitations, ...
>   **`proc`** a class for proceedings based on the article class.
>   **`minimal`** is as small as it can get. It only sets a page size and a base font. It is mainly used for debugging purposes.
>   **`report`** for longer reports containing several chapters, small books, thesis, ...
>   **`book`** for real books
>   **`slides`** for slides. The class uses big sans serif letters.
>   **`memoir`** for changing sensibly the output of the document. It is based on the `book` class, but you can create any kind of document with it [(1)](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf)
>   **`letter`**  For writing letters.
>   **`beamer`**  For writing presentations (see [LaTeX/Presentations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Presentations)).

which lists the main classes and is a good starting point, but the description is too short and still leaves one wondering when it would be more suitable to choose one class over the other and what the characteristics of each class is. Furthermore, the list is not exhaustive I think, given that I know at least one more document class that is not there (the `standalone` class, as I mentioned).

So my question is: what are the available classes of documents in LaTeX, and could you provide a brief description of the class and the situations where it would be recommended?

Please give only one class per answer.

Comment: There is no such thing as a definitive list, so at best you will get a partial answer here. There are a lot of classes for journals, for example.

Comment: @Joseph: I imagine classes can be created at any time, so I know what you mean. I am more interested in finding out some unknown package that might be useful to me and also understanding the differences between some of the "well-known" packages, because to date I have only ever used the three I mentioned in my question (article, beamer and standalone).

Comment: I think this question is too open ended and just voted to close. There are literally thousands of classes out there. I would be much more interested in similar questions by topic, e.g. we already have classes for letters, maybe also classes for slides, classes for cv's, etc. People will search by topic.

Comment: @Navarro Don't vote to close it, it should be moved to community wiki, that way this can stay open for discussion and maybe we can learn something from it, it's a nice general question for beginners looking to get a foothold in LaTeX.

Comment: @EricR: it has been community wiki from the moment I asked the question....

Comment: @Vivi, sorry, must've missed that, thought I saw a close button on it or I just misinterpreted what Navarro said.

Comment: The `standalone` class actually simply loads a real class but uses the `preview` package to reduce the page size to the content. It is supposed to be used for subfiles holding only picture or similar code which are then included into a main document. The `standalone` class and package allow this files to be compiled standalone or as part of the main document without adjusting the file.

Comment: I'm not sure this is an answerable question.  Why is KOMA-Script a "better" answer than beamer?  If the question were refined to "What are the available document classes for a short article?" such as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16204/which-package-to-use-for-presentations-beamer-prosper-or-other for presentations that make sense.

Comment: Looks like this one wasn't mentioned before: https://ctan.org/topic/class , an overview of available dcoument classes on CTAN.

Answer (score 164):

New working link: [Al­ter­na­tive LaTeX class(es)](https://ctan.org/topic/class)

---

**Original answer:**

There's a category in the TeX Catalogue: [Alternative Document Classes](http://texcatalogue.ctan.org/bytopic.html#classes) (web archive [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171222231507/http://texcatalogue.ctan.org/bytopic.html#classes)).

Comment: To a large extent, imo this is **the** answer to the question asked.

Comment: In this case however, anything else than a link would become obsolete rapidly as the list seems to evolve a lot.

Answer (score 109):

The classes in the [KOMA-Script bundle](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)* (`scrbook`, `scrreprt`, `scrartcl`, `scrlttr2`) provide replacements of standard classes (`book`, `report`, `article` and `letter` respectively). They offer lots of configuration options to accommodate different layouts without using ugly hacks. Generally I think they are nearer to European (and in particular German) typography conventions than the standard classes are.

* see also the [german homepage](http://www.komascript.de/) of KOMA-Script.

Comment: These classes add a lot of extra functions to those provided by the base classes. This means that using one of the KOMA-Script classes is often a way to reduce or avoid entirely needing to load additional packages to get the output desired. See also `memoir`.

Comment: Would I need more time to learn plain Latex and add some extras or learn directly Koma?

Comment: @skan I think it's worthwhile to learn both. Even knowing some of the added functionality of the KOMA classes, I still find myself using about a dozen extra packages with them on a regular basis (assuming that's what you mean with extras). Having to avoid packages is not at all the intent behind KOMA; as stated in this answer, it's more about supplying additional configuration options for things like sectioning, tocs, layout, etc. built-in.

Answer (score 67):

The `memoir` class is based on the `book` class. It implements a lot of design facilities that with other classes usually need loading additional packages. The result is a feature-rich, customizable and powerful class, especially useful for designing books.

`memoir` offers an extensive manual with more than 500 pages ([here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/memoir/memman.pdf)) containing also examples for the design of a book and of a thesis.

Comment: By the way, does it make sense to use the memoir class for articles? I noticed that it provides a package option "article", but I have never actually tried it.

Comment: @Jukka Suomela you need to make some tweaks to use memoir for articles: you probably want to do `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` and `\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}` you might also want to pass the `openany,oneside` options to the document class as well.

Comment: @JukkaSuomela ... and also `\pagestyle{plain}` for empty headers and centered page numbering in the footer (default for the article class).  I wouldn't advise using the `article` option of the memoir class (instead of the above tweaks), because it will most likely won't work as you expect it so (for example, sections are typeset in a bigger font than chapters, so there is no convenient way to emulate subsections in this setting).

Answer (score 67):

I've grown to love `standalone` recently, particularly for `tikz`-graphics. Never again I will have to run `pdfcrop` on the output from my `pdflatex` run, because that is what the `standalone` class does.

Comment: But sometimes it doesn't work.  For example, if I use \being{pmatrix} it gives an error.

Comment: @skan: `standalone` is designed for block content, if you need paragraph content use it with the `varwidth` option.

Comment: Please note that the `standalone` class is not a "real" class, as it is for standalone diagrams not for whole documents. It loads `article` class in the background (which can be changed using the `class=<classname>` option).

Comment: @skan: it works 
```\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$
\displaystyle
\begin{pmatrix}
  x & x \\
  y & y 
\end{pmatrix}
$
\end{document}
```

But fails when you use double dollar.

Answer (score 53):

The [`exam` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/exam):

> Provides a class `exam`, which eases production of exams, even by a
>   LaTeX novice. Simple commands are provided to:
>
> - create questions, parts of questions, subparts of parts, and subsubparts of subparts, all with optional point values;
> - create a grading table, indexed either by question number (listing each question and the total possible points for that question) or by
>     page number (listing each page with points and the total possible
>     points for that page);
> - create headers and footers that are each specified in three parts: one part to be left justified, one part to be centered, and one part
>     to be right justified, in the manner of
>     [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr)
>
> Headers and/or footers can be different on the first page of the exam,
>   can be different on the last page of the exam, and can vary depending
>   on whether the page number is odd or even, or on whether the current
>   page continues a question from a previous page, or on whether the last
>   question on the current page continues onto the following page.
>
> Multiple line headers and/or footers are allowed, and it's easy to
>   increase the part of the page devoted to headers and/or footers to
>   allow for this.

A quick example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question[10]
Why is there air?
\question
What if there were no air?
\begin{parts}
\part[5]
Describe the effect on the balloon industry.
\part[5]
Describe the effect on the aircraft industry.
\end{parts}
\question[20]
\begin{parts}
\part
Define the universe. Give three examples.
\part
If the universe were to end, how would you know?
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 46):

I think the base classes probably deserve a single answer. (`minimal`, `letter` and `slides` are different enough to need their own answers.)

The **`article`** class is, as the name suggests, intended for writing articles. This means relatively short documents which do not contain chapters or parts, only sections, subsections, *etc.* As one of the base classes, the formatting is pretty basic. However, as the article class does provide the basic function most people expect from LaTeX it is often used with modifications for longer documents.

The **`report`** class is intended for longer documents which will have chapters, while **`book`** is intended for very large documents. The standard settings for `report` and `book` are slightly different from `article`. For example, the default for `article` is to put the `\maketitle` information at the top of the first page, whereas `report` and `book` use separate title pages. `book` includes pre-defined shortcuts for the `\frontmatter` (unnumbered chapters with roman page numbers), `\mainmatter` (numbered chapters and arabic page numbers) and `\backmatter`.

All of the base classes have very basic formatting. Some of this can be questioned, but the LaTeX Project have made it clear that with so much use of these classes, the decisions are 'fixed'. As a result, modifying the base classes is an approach many people use for their own documents.

Answer (score 42):

The [`leaflet` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/leaflet):

> A document class to create small hand-outs (flyers) that fit on a
>   single sheet of paper which is then folded twice. Pages are rearranged
>   by LaTeX so that they print correctly on a single sheet — no external
>   script is necessary.

See [this example output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51725/5764):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ugh...  that's what [inkscape](http://inkscape.org) is for.

Comment: @naught101 Actually, that's what desktop publishing is for. There's no problem in preparing those kinds of leaflets with LaTeX, though.

Comment: I used this for a family tree leaflet to give to relatives at a recent wedding. I think it works nicely :)

Answer (score 38):

The [paper](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/paper) document class is similar to `ar­ti­cle` but with a default look more European in my opinion, but this class have some new lay­out op­tions and font com­mands for sec­tions. Define also a `key­words` en­vi­ron­ment and com­mands as `sub­ti­tle`, `in­sti­tu­tion`, `\smalltableofcontents`, etc.

Unfortunately `texdoc paper` give only a brief English abstract but is not too hard discover the options and useful commands in the code between the German text.

An example with defined `section` font (only to add color),  and also a custom `keyword` name:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,latin]{paper} 
\usepackage{babel}  
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\sectionfont{\large\sf\bfseries\color{black!70!blue}} 
\renewcommand\keywordname{Clavem verborum}
\title{Minimum exemplum laborandi}
\subtitle{Exemplum apparentia \texttt{paper} tabellae\\
\hfill\includegraphics[height=2cm]{/home/fran/logo}
\vspace{-2cm}}
\author{Ph. D. Franciscus Studiosum Somniantis} 
\institution{Ignotum Universitas \\ 
Ad requiem centrum Scientiarum}


\begin{document} 
\twocolumn[\maketitle 
\hrule 
\smalltableofcontents
\begin{abstract} {\lipsum[12]} \end{abstract}
\begin{keywords}
MWE, \LaTeX, document class, \texttt{paper},
\texttt{article}, dummy text    
\end{keywords}
\hrule\bigskip
]


\section{Introductio} 
Some introduction. \lipsum[2]
\section{Materia et modos} 
More dummy text. \lipsum[4] 

\begin{table}[b]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc}
\toprule
& I &  II & III & IV & V & VI \\
\midrule
Vandali     & 123 & 456 & 678 & 321 & 644 & 768  \\ 
Visigothorum & 021 & 229 & 678 & 123 & 456 & 678 \\     
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Visigothi cum Romanis foederati Hispaniam ingressi sunt et contra Vandalos. Mortem comitis utraque pugna.} 
\end{table}

\section{Consequitur} 
These are the results. \lipsum[1]
\section{Disputatio} 
\lipsum[4] 
\section{Conclusionibus}
\lipsum[5]
\end {document}
```

With defaults sections, but with the `center` and `twocolumn` options (obviously now without the command `\twocolumn[...]` and with minor changes to adapt that was within):

[image: MWE2]

Comment: does it handle floats in the two-column layout well?

Comment: @Ingo, as far I know, as well as the standard article.

Comment: Index is latin?

Comment: @Peregring-lk I not an expert, but babel is correct, index (nominative singular) is latin. See in Google books René Aubert, 1552: _Index rerum et verborum, quae in Pandectis tractantur, copiosißimus._

Comment: @Fran Thank you for the reference hehe. My question was half a joke (because latin is not the issue here), but half a real question (because I was a little surprised). I've thought only you have forgot to rename the index title (and I've nor known babel has support for latin also neither seen the `latin` option).

Comment: Just nitpicking, but I have more doubts about "clavem verborum" instead -- if I remember enough Latin, it means *key (direct object) of the words*. I'd rather use something like *verba cardinalia*

Comment: @FedericoPoloni you're probably right. I think that I saw "clave verborum"  somewhere but anyway consider my latin words just a  simple Lore-ipsum extension.

Answer (score 37):

The `beamer` class is designed for creating presentations (although it can be used for academic posters in conjunction with the `beamerposter` package). It provides a wide range of graphical functions for making 'good looking' presentations. The specialist functions in `beamer` include modifications to standard macros (such as the lists `itemize` and `enumerate`) so that they can be revealed partwise. The class is designed to be able to also produce article-style material by including the appropriate. The documentation also provides advice on what makes a good presentation.

Answer (score 33):

Sorry about violating your "one class per answer" request, but I feel that these three should be included in the same post: `amsart`, `amsbook`, and `amsproc`. They come from the `ams-LaTeX` collection prepared by the American Mathematical Society and are the standard document classes to use for preparing documents for publication by the AMS. As their names suggest, they are modified versions of the `article`, `book`, and `proc` classes to adhere to the AMS's house style, and also incorporate the features of the package `amsthm` and load supplementary mathematics packages `amsmath` and `amsfonts`. For more detail one should refer to [the website for the collection](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/tex/amslatex).

Comment: amsthm is not loaded into the ams classes; its features are built in, and differ slightly from the defaults of the separate package.  amsfonts is loaded, but can be suppressed by using the document class option <code>noamsfonts</code>.

Answer (score 33):

The [tufte-la­tex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex) package pro­vide two classes: `tufte-handout` and `tufte-book` in­spired, re­spec­tively, by hand­outs and books cre­ated by the work of Ed­ward Tufte.

Tufte’s style is known for its extensive use of sidenotes, tight integration of graphics with text, and well-set typography.

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout} 
\author{by Fran}
\title{A Minimal Working Example}
\usepackage{lipsum,blindtext}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % Demo option for MWE without image
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{marginfigure}
\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{Scrooge}
\caption{\blindtext}
\end{marginfigure}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 33):

The [hitec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hitec) document class de­signed for use for doc­u­men­ta­tion of high-tech­nol­ogy com­pa­nies. It is a hack on the standard `article` class, but it looks very different. In fact, one of the design aims was to escape the academic look of the well-known LaTeX document classes.

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{hitec}
\author{by Fran}
\title{A Minimal Working Example}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 30):

`moderncv` is a class for typesetting modern curriculums vitae. If offers both a classic and a casual style. It is fairly customizable allowing the definition of your own style regarding colors and fonts.

More classes useful for writing a CV can be found in the [CV category](https://ctan.org/topic/cv) of the TeX Catalogue.

Comment: your link could not be retrieved!

Comment: @OLSAY I updated the link.

Comment: The new link is now: https://ctan.org/topic/cv

Answer (score 21):

Okay, one class per answer, so I'll make a start with something basic.

The `minimal` class is the absolute minimum you load and actually have LaTeX work. It's only intended for testing purposes, as it doesn't define many things you almost always expect (things like titling and sectioning commands). You would not usually use the `minimal` class yourself as it is so basic that there will not really be suitable for real work.

Comment: Some more on `minimal` at [why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided)

Answer (score 21):

[`REVTeX`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1) is a class designed for the American Physical Society (APS). It can produce output which is ready for production printing for a range of APS journals, depending on class options. The class provides a wide range of specialist functions needed by the journals, for example modifying how the `\author` macro works to improve the meta-data control. The `REVTeX` documentation includes a wide range of advice not only on the class itself but also on wider LaTeX use.

Answer (score 18):

The [`extsizes` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/extsizes) provides the classes `extarticle`, `extreport`, `extbook`, `extletter` and `extproc`. They can be used instead of a corresponding base class and allow choosing a base font of a size between 8pt and 20pt.

When you're in need of a base font size that standard classes don't provide, these classes adjust commands like `\tiny`, `\Huge` etc. fitting to your desired base font size, further they adjust page dimensions, list and float dimensions accordingly.

Note that the KOMA-Script classes allow *any* font size specified in *any* TeX measurement unit so they might be considered as well when specific font sizes are needed.

Answer (score 18):

There are also many classes made specifically for formatting Masters and PhD theses. This is especially true in the U.S., where formatting requirements are often highly specified by particular universities and usually by people who have absolutely no sense about nice looking formatting.  Some of these classes are available on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/search?phrase=thesis) (search for your university or just 'thesis') but many are unfortunately only circulated locally within a university. Classes that are available on CTAN and actively maintained are likley to be your best choice, if they are available.

If your university does not have a class available, and you are thinking of creating one, I would recommend basing it on one of the 'augmented' classes such as `memoir` or `scrbook` rather than one of the basic classes since, as other answers note, both of these classes provide non-hacky ways of implementing all sorts of formatting requirements, and both are extensively documented.

Answer (score 17):

[`bookcover`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookcover) is a class specifically designed to create book cover and dust jacket layouts.

[Layout example 1](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/bookcover/example1.pdf):

[image]

[Layout example 2](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/bookcover/example2.pdf):

[image]

Answer (score 16):

In a slightly different track of answers, I would like to mention the `cd` document class [[ 1 ]](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cd) that is designed for creating cd covers. It has

> Easy batch printing with crop marks, full typographical control,
>   extended foreign language support, fully open text-based format for
>   easy copy-and-modify operations, and so on.

Although the examples in the documentation [[ 2 ]](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cd/cd.pdf) are all about music disks, I personally use it when I have to distribute code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{cd}
\begin{document}
\covertext{
    Pouya\\ \vspace{1cm}
    \textbf {Full title of the work}
}

\leftspine{\textnormal{Pouya}}
\rightspine{\textbf{Shorter title for the sides}}
\lefttracklist{
    \track Code
    \track Documentation
    \track Notes for users
    \track Demos
}
\leftinfo{Some example information}
\makecover\par
\makeback\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

`novel` is new in 2017. It is specifically intended for printed novels and short story collections, not for math or theses. It offers built-in formats for the most common print-on-demand book sizes, as well as allowing any size. It also has built-in PDF/X capability that does not rely on other methods. It also provides support for converting cover artwork to PDF/X. The documentation is elaborate, and is addressed to writers rather than programmers. Note that this document class is not for e-books, it is only for printed books.

It uses LuaLaTeX, Open Type fonts, and utf-8 exclusively. Needs TeXLive 2016 or later, or current MiKTeX.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

[`powerdot`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/powerdot) is a good alternative to the beamer class. Presentations can be developed easily. It provides many styles and allows creating your own style. powerdot offers automatic overlays, notes and a handout mode, further it supports LyX.

It's intended to replace the older classes `prosper` and `HA-prosper`.

powerdot requires PSTricks. So, it may be a good choice when you're using PSTricks in a presentation, but it cannot benefit from pdfTeX features.

Comment: can you explain more? what is the difference between powerdot and beamer?

Comment: powerdot requires PSTricks. So, it may be a good choice when you're using PSTricks in a presentation, but it cannot benefit from pdfTeX features. I usually prefer beamer with pdfLaTeX and TikZ.

Comment: Stefan, put that in your answer! You can edit it! I am sure this info will be useful for someone, but here in the comments the chances of it being read are slimmer.

Comment: Ok, Vivi, done, I've edited the answer and provided more information.

Comment: I still don't understand from your answer why would anyone prefer powerdot to beamer? (I'm putting the question this way because I think beamer is much more popular.) Obviously dependency on PSTricks is not a feature. Thanks in advance for explaining.

Comment: @Roman: it's a different approach, another way of coding, another visual appearance. One may use it for distinguishing from the popular beamer styles or if he doesn't like the beamer syntax. And who likes to reuse prosper code, migration to powerdot would be easier. I would prefer beamer, as I said, as beamer is capable of doing most, though it's always good to have alternatives.

Answer (score 14):

The [`apa6` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/apa6):

> It provides a full set of facilities in three different output modes
>   (journal-like appearance, double-spaced manuscript, LaTeX-like
>   document), in contrast to the earlier [`apa6e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/apa6e), which only
>   formats double-spaced manuscripts in APA style. The class can mask
>   author identity for copies for use in masked peer review.
>
> Citations are provided using the [`apacite`](http://ctan.org/pkg/apacite) bundle; the
>   class requires that package if citations are to be typeset.

Answer (score 13):

The [`kerntest` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/kerntest). From the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/kerntest/kerntest.pdf) abstract:

> This class makes it easy to generate tables that show many diﬀerent kerning
>   pairs of an arbitrary font, usable by LaTeX. It shows the kerning values that
>   are used by the the font by default.
>
> In addition, this class enables the user to alternate the kernings and
>   to observe the results. Kerning pairs can be deﬁned for groups of similar
>   glyphs at once. Automatically, an `mtx` ﬁle is generated that can be loaded
>   by `fontinst` to introduce the user-made kernings into the virtual font for
>   LaTeX.

[image]

```
\documentclass[family=ptm]{kerntest}
\kernsetup{encoding=T1,series=bx,shape=n,example=M}
\kernsetup{size=17.28pt,baselineskip=17pt,papersize=a4paper}
\kernsetup{extraname=example,color=true,footer=false}
\newglyphclass{right}{A}{A,Aring,Adieresis,Abreve[500]}
\newglyphclass{left}{A}{A,Aring,Adieresis,Abreve[500]}
\newglyphclass{right}{fullstop}{period,comma}
\newglyphclass{left}{fullstop}{period,comma}
\begin{document}
\begin{kerntable}
\testkern{016}{-30}{046}{-30}{017} decimal \\
\testkern{"10}{-}{"2C}{-}{"11} hexadecimal \\
\testkern{'020}{-}{'101}{-80}{'021} octal \\
\testkern{quotedblleft}{-}{Aring}{-80}{quotedblright} by name\\
\testkern{quotedblleft}{-100}{AE}{-}{quotedblright} \\
\testkern{quotedblleft}{-}{B}{-60}{quotedblright} \\
\testkern{quotedblleft}{-}{C}{-}{quotedblright} \\
\testkern{T}{-}{f}{+90}{T} \\
\testkern{quotedblbase}{-60}{T}{-}{quotedblleft} \\
\testkern{quotedblbase}{-}{Adieresis}{-}{quotedblleft} \\
\testkern{quotedblbase}{-}{A}{-200}{quotedblleft} \\
\testkern{quotedblbase}{-}{Aring}{-}{quotedblleft} \\
\testkern{quotedblbase}{-}{Abreve}{-}{quotedblleft} \\
\testkern{guillemotright}{-55}{V}{-55}{guillemotleft} \\
\end{kerntable}
\end{document
```

Answer (score 13):

The [`pressrelease`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pressrelease) class is provided for typesetting press releases.

A press release is a written statement to inform the media of
forthcoming events, new products, awards or any other type of news
item. A press release should be a compact document that briefly
outlines the main details of the news item. Therefore press releases
are usually no longer than a single page. Hard copies are typically
double-spaced to allow the journalist room to scribble notes. The
end of the press release is signalled by three hash (`#`) signs
(end of release marker).

The following is a minimal example, taken from the package's sample repository [`sample-pressrelease.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pressrelease/samples/sample-pressrelease.tex):

[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{pressrelease}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\PRlogo{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}}

\PRcompany{Some Company}
\PRdepartment{Some Department}
\PRcontact{Ann Other}
\PRlocation{Some City}
\PRaddress{1 The Street\\The Town\\AB1 2YZ}
\PRphone{01234 56789}
\PRmobile{07123456789}
\PRfax{01234 56788}
\PRurl{http://www.some-company.com/~abc}
\PRemail{ann.other@some-company.com}
\PRhours{9:00--17:30 Mon--Fri}

\PRheadline{Some amazing news}
\PRsubheadline{subheading}

\begin{document}

\begin{pressrelease}

This is an example press release. Keep it short and use the third
person. Avoid the use of exclamation marks and all-caps. Put all the
pertinent details in the first paragraph. Answer who, what, when,
where and why.

Use short paragraphs. Try not to exceed 500 words. Keep to the point
and avoid jargon. This is the default layout. The image is from the
\textsf{mwe} package.

\begin{about}
Some Company was set up in 2014.
\end{about}

\end{pressrelease}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

`slides` is the basic class for presentations. It predated presenting using projectors, and shares with the other base classes the somewhat questionable layout choices. Other options such as `powerdot` or `beamer` are very much better choices than `slides`.

Answer (score 12):

Consider the ltxdoc class. It's small, fast, and frills free. Although it was designed for documenting LaTeX source files, it's very useful for producing your own documentation and notes, even if you are not interested in the 'doc' format or developing your own .dtx, .cls, or .sty files.  Since ltxdoc loads the article class, you can easily customize it by passing options to the article class or loading other packages.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage[hmargin={3.5 cm,1.5cm},
   top=1.5cm, marginpar=3.5cm
   ]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
   \hypersetup{colorlinks, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\title{\textsf{Device Notes}}
\author{Ann Nonymous\\Skunkworks Division}
\maketitle
\abstract{\lipsum[3]}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\setlength{\columnsep}{5pc}
    \protect\begin{multicols}{2}}
\section{The Device}
\lipsum[30]
\section{How to Install}
\lipsum[33]
\section{How to Use}
\lipsum[37]
\section{Other Applications}
\lipsum[41]
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\end{multicols}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I find it funny that the first line after "Abstract" is indented, but not after the section heading ...

Answer (score 9):

The [`newlfm` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/newlfm)

> ...in­te­grates the `let­ter` class with `fan­cy­hdr` and `ge­om­e­try` to au­to­mat­i­cally make let­ter­head sta­tionery. Use­ful for writ­ing let­ters, fax, and memos. You can set up an ad­dress book us­ing ‘wrap­per’ macros. You put all the in­for­ma­tion for a per­son into a wrap­per and then put the wrap­per in a doc­u­ment. The class han­dles let­ter­heads au­to­mat­i­cally. You place the ob­ject for the let­ter­head (pic­ture, in­for­ma­tion, etc.) in a box and all siz­ing is set au­to­mat­i­cally.

From [the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/newlfm/newlfm.pdf), this is how one would write a simple letter:

```
\documentclass[stdletter]{newlfm}
\nameto{George Bush} \addrto{\parbox{2in}{The White House \\ Washington, DC}}
\namefrom{Paul Thompson} \addrfrom{\parbox{2in}{The Pink House \\ Belleville, IL}}
\begin{document}
\closeline{Sincerely yours,} \greetto{Dear Mr. Bush,}
\begin{newlfm}
How are the azaleas?
\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

#### new url

http://netgear.rohidekar.com/latex/latex_document_classes.pdf

[image]

#### original answer

I've attempted to provide a concise cheat-sheet of all the ones listed in the question here:

https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/sridhar/pdf/latex_document_classes.pdf

I hope someone finds it useful or is inspired to make something better. I'm a bit surprised there isn't a well-known visual reference of this sort.

Comment: an explanation on that pdf would totally rock!

Comment: I'm feeling too lazy, plus I barely get the difference between some of them :)

Comment: Broken document…

Comment: Oh yeah my s3 space was shut down. If I don't fix it in the next 30 days please remind me - if anyone cares enough

Comment: its not accessible. please make it available

Comment: Updated. Hope it's not an anticlimax.

Answer (score 8):

[`refman`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refman) provides document classes (report- and article-style) for writing technical reference manuals. It offers a wide left margin for notes to the reader, like some of the manuals distributed by Adobe.

Here is an example from the [layout changes documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/refman/layout_e.pdf):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[`ctex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ctex) contains a set of LaTeX classes and packages for Chinese typesetting. Specifically it provides the "default" classes [`ctexart`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/chinese/ctex/ctexart.cls), [`ctexbook`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/chinese/ctex/ctexbook.cls) and [`ctexrep`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/chinese/ctex/ctexrep.cls).

Answer (score 4):

The [`huawei` document class](//ctan.org/pkg/huawei) helps you design your work documents and presentations keeping the code short and the style elegant enough both for management and technical papers.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The [flashcards](https://ctan.org/pkg/flashcards) class provides an interface to produce ... well, is not hard guess it yourself, is not it?

> [image: mwe]

The [source code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134150/11604) of the image is in  [Specification of the Layout for Q-A Reference Cards (Flashcards, Visual Cards)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134052/specification-of-the-layout-for-q-a-reference-cards-flashcards-visual-cards).

Note that also exist the class `flacards`(without the "sh" of flash) for the same purpose,  and in TeXLive, the old`flashcard` (without the final "s" and without user's manual), so be careful that a mistake in the name could load a wrong class without warning you a this point.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main thing to keepin mind is we are not dealing with a word processor here. This is a document language layout scenario.
A different mindset applies and needs to be adopted.
You create the layout parameters.
For example, the `leaflet` layout could be achieved within the `article` class, employing the package `multicols`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`minimalist` package](//ctan.org/pkg/minimalist) offers a LaTeX style file (`minimalist.sty`) and two classes (`minimart.cls` and `minimbook.cls`) to typeset articles or books in a simple and clear way. These classes currently have native support for English, French, German, Italian, Portuguese (European and Brazilian), and Spanish typesetting. They compile with any major TeX engine.

[image]