# Most useful additions in KOMA-Script?

Tags: packages, koma-script, document-classes, big-list

(Background: I'm a beginner who will mostly use LaTeX for university articles and reports, but no math. Also, as I reside in Canada, the German typography conventions, which I understand KOMA-Script supports better than LaTeX, are less relevant).

I've read that the KOMA-Script package has a lot of improvements for the default document classes. Yet the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf)'s length, about 250 pages, is somewhat daunting. I plan to read the chapters I'm interested in anyway but it'd be useful to have some pointers about low hanging fruits. I searched the site and [other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/782/what-are-the-available-documentclass-types-and-their-uses/787#787) answers say KOMA-Script adds improvements but do not delve into details.

I'll ask this as a community wiki topic and, since the audience of this site is international, feel free to mention German typography if KOMA-Script is better there.

Comment: That's @Caramdir, I just exchanged [tag:best-practices] for [tag:big-list], the rest was the platform jumbling things around. Even more interestingly, I didn't remove the space in the title, that must've been done automagically. (Btw, you can use `[tag:tagname]` in comments.) Edit: As I think about it -- I don't have any expertise in KOMA -- the [tag:packages] tag should only be kept if we're discussing packages that are used _on top_ of KOMA, if it's only KOMA, this tag is not necessary because the specific "package" has its own tag.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Unlike memoir, the KOMA-Script-classes do not add the functionality of dozens of packages to the LaTeX core - but the KOMA-additions are useful and extremely easy to handle. Roughly in order of the documentation:

- Customizable type area with default values that also  (contrary to the standard classes) work well for letter- and A4-paper,
- Support for arbitrarily chosen font sizes (e.g. 10.5pt),
- Ability to change font size mid-document,
- Customization of the font attributes of many document elements,
- Enhanced `\maketitle` features (e.g. `\subtitle`),
- `\addpart`, `\addchap`, and `\addsec` commands producing unnumbered parts, chapters, and sections that are nevertheless included in the table of contents,
- Options to include the bibliography, the index etc. in the table of contents,
- `parskip` option that is more powerful than the package of the same name,
- Configurable footnotes (including some features of the footmisc package),
- Option `open=left` to always start chapters on *left* pages,
- Consistent formatting of every "listofsomething" (e.g. "chapter gaps" in the "List of Listings"),
- Lots of little things.

Answer (score 26):

KOMA-Script brings even more than extended classes: it offers packages to allow other classes to benefit from its features.

Here are some of them:

- `typearea` provides automatic calculation of layout dimensions according to classical typography,
- `scrlayer-scrpage` (`scrpage2` is superseded) is a feature-rich replacement for fancyhdr,
- `scrextend` brings various KOMA-features together with non-KOMA classes,
- `scrlfile` helps managing package dependencies,
- `tocbasic` manages table of contents and lists of tables and figures and so on,
- `tocstyle` helps with formatting table of contents and lists of floats.

Answer (score 16):

In addition to what has already been mentioned the KOMA bundle provides the letter class scrlttr2 which is a huge improvement over the standard letter class. scrlttr2 is both easy to configure and has a lot of features including the option of generating letters from address lists.