# How to set the chapter style in report class

Tags: header-footer, chapters

When a chapter starts, it appears as, e.g.,

> Chapter 1
>   Introduction

and it then in upper left corner of each page in the chapter the name appears as

> CHAPTER 1 INTRODUCTION

But I want that only the name of the chapter (i.e. just “INTRODUCTION”) appears there.

I have no problem with page numbering.

Comment: Welcome to {TeX}! It would be great if you write your question with a bit more care. The question tells that you don't even want the chapter number to be printed. Is this true? And do you really use all capital letters in chapter headings?

Comment: I copied the text from the duplicate question herin. Btw.: if you change `\documentclass[...]{report}` into `\documentclass[...]{scrreprt}` you would notice the headings will change like desired, also without the (in my opinion ugly) upper case. Some other defaults change, but may easily be adjusted. `scrreprt` belongs to the KOMA-Script classes which can be used similar to standard classes but offer [many more features](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1351/most-useful-additions-in-koma-script).

Comment: I edited the question according to how I understand your comments. If this is wrong, please revert it.

Answer (score 10):

From your comments I can see that you mean the marks in the page header but not the chapter headings.

The [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package is very popular for customizing page headers and footers. Here's a minimal way to change your header like desired, if everything is default:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}}
```

See also the [`fancyhdr` documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf).

---

Here's the solution for the chapter heading, in case you like to do it similar to the page header, for consistency:

You could use the [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package, for example write in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
```

This way by `\chapter{Introduction}` you would get:

**1 Introduction**

Have a look at the [documentation to `titlesec`](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf).

I guess you wish to keep the numbering, otherwise you could simply write `\chapter*{Introduction}`. Further I assume you don't wish to write everything in capital letters - or do you?

I prefer `scrreprt` instead of `report`. This class is similar to report but provides many further features. It's default chapter headings style matches the one desired by you.

Comment: in this way in start of chapter, chapter1 Introduction, is not coming which i want.But in left corner of every page of the chapter it comes as CHAPTER1 INTRODUCTION which i do not want i want only INTRODUCTION which is name of the chapter in every page and no problem with page number

Comment: @chaman, sorry I can't figure out what exactly it is you want. Are we talking about the chapter title that only appears once, such as "1 Introduction" or do you want to know how to change your heading that appear on every page of the chapter?

Comment: yes i want to change heading that appear in every page of the chapter it appears as CHAPTER1 INTRODUCTION i do not want cHAPTER1 i want only INTRODUCTION i mean name of the chapter in every page.

Comment: @chaman: ok, so you mean the style of the marks in the headings - the original question did not say that. I will show a solution (or somebody else does before).