# How can I redefine the base font size and change the size of the page number on chapter pages?

Tags: chapters, page-numbering, fontsize

I've got a problem when editing a TeX file. I've changed `\normalsize` to 20pt by

```
\newcommand{\mysize}{\fontsize{20pt}{\baselinestretch}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\mysize}
```

and this caused the font size of page number in the chapter page can not be modified when using the fancy macro package. So can anyone help me?

Then (after reading the now deleted comments) I've used the following command

```
\documentclass[fontsize=20]{scrbook}
```

but the problem is still can not be solved.

Comment: I guess that you should read in the fancyhdr manual the part about "redefining plain style".

Answer (score 3):

Extending my comment: Simply redefining `\normalsize` is not a good idea. There are further lengths which are chosen matching the base font size, specifically regarding vertical spacing. For example, if you look into the file `book.clo`, which contains class options for `book`, you can see it.

For a consistent change I recommend changing the document class.

- the [extsizes](http://ctan.org/pkg/extsizes) bundle provides classes similar to standard classes offering a base font size from 9pt to 20pt.
- [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) can also be used with 20pt and more. In this regard, the option `extrafontsizes` may be useful. For very high font size a scalable font should be used.
- [KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes, such as `scrartcl`, `scrbook` and `scrreprt` support arbitrary base font sizes. You could even user other units than pt to specify the size.

Since KOMA-Script classes offer [many more features](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1351/most-useful-additions-in-koma-script), this would be my choice.

The further way depends on how your're producing the footer. On chapter starting pages, the page style is `plain`.

- With default page styles the base font size should be used, so there's no problem.
- With `fancyhdr`, you could simply add `\small`, `\normalsize` or any orher font size command to the beginning of your header and footer macros. If necessary, use `\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\cfoot{\small\thepage}}`, like Ulrike already said in comments to question and to this answer.
- With a KOMA-Script class, I recommend to use `scrpage2` instead of `fancyhdr`. Since it belongs to the KOMA-Script bundle, it's very well integrated with the classes. That should also solve the problem. If necessary, use a font size command such as `\small`, `\tiny` or just `\normalsize` within header and footer commands. Note: for `plain` pages do it also within the optional argument, such as `\cfoot[\tiny\thepage]{\tiny\thepage}`. `scrpage2` is explained in the [KOMA-Script manual](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/scrguien.pdf).

With KOMA-Script there are more and even easier possible solutions. You could use `\addtokomafont` or `\setkomafont` for specifying the font size. For example:

```
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\tiny}
```

Further font option names, which you might use in this regard: `pagehead`, `pageheadfoot`, `pagefoot`.

Comment: Yes, the scrpage2 is involved in my tex file, and I used the command: lefoot, refoot,rofoot, lofoot which used \tiny command to control font size of foot number, but the page number in chapter page's is not changed, is actually 20pt.

Comment: @buddy.qin: try my last advice and example using `\addtokomafont`.