# Downsides of switching from default LaTeX document classes to KOMA-Script variants?

Tags: koma-script, document-classes

I'm considering switching from the `article` class to KOMA-Script's `scrartcl`, due to the availability of a `\subtitle` environment - a rather weak reason. I've read the [list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1351/5640) of useful features / benefits of KOMA-Script classes, but I wonder - are there issues which should discourage me from switching? e.g. compatibility with certain packages, multi-language/directionality gotchas, and so on?

Comment: `\subtitle` environment? It is a simple variable for a fixed title creation. Not really a reason to change.

Comment: You can get the manual by typing `texdoc koma` into a terminal and see, if you need the features KOMA provides.

Comment: And also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73248/what-packages-are-incompatible-with-koma-script