# The purpose of KOMA-scripts

Tags: xetex, koma-script

I want to ask a question about KOMA-scripts.

I'm a beginner in LaTeX and I'm trying to understand the term `KOMA-Scripts` that appears repeatedly throughout the [LaTeX wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_Page_Headers_and_Footers).

As far as I can make out, the current version of LaTeX is LaTeX2e, and [KOMA-Scripts](https://codeyarns.com/tech/2010-03-29-latex-koma-script.html#:%7E:text=KOMA%2DScript%20is%20a%20LaTeX,for%20the%20letter%20paper%20size.) apparently introduce update the keywords to the standard document classes e.g. `article`, `book`, `letter` etc, while introducing new packages e.g. `scrlayer-scrpage`. In the tutorial shown [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_Page_Headers_and_Footers#Customizing_with_scrlayer-scrpage), I see that there is no change to the standard document class, nor any mention of KOMA-Scripts being imported, yet it exists in the environment and simply one can import scrlayer-scrpage` with incredible ease.

However, I've failed to find any resource on the internet that provides a comprehensive analysis of how KOMA-Scripts work and its purpose for a beginner like myself, especially when learning how to personalise headers and footers in LaTeX.

What are KOMA-Scripts, in layman's terms, and how are they implemented in LaTeX?

Comment: they are not scripts in the sense of programming language scripts koma is just a reference to the author s' name, they area alternative set of (more European influenced) document classes as al alternative to article/report/book that come in the core latex.

Comment: tex distributions have (literally) thousands of contributed classes and packages extending latex in various ways the koma script classes are just one of those (one of the more popular and long standing ones) this question is probably a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1351/most-useful-additions-in-koma-script

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script

Comment: KOMA-Scripts not introduce anything in standard classes, but provide alternative classes with a more "European" style,  that in addition to the common standard commands of  standard classes also provides a lot of  own commands and from several packages,  to make,  for instance, a chapter epigraph, that is not available in the standard book.  If you have a complete distro installed,  just run "texdoc koma" as you will see the 568 pages of the manual.

Answer (score 2):

LaTeX was written with anglo-american typographical traditions in mind. KOMA-Skript offers a way to let your document look more "continental european".

Comment: You are right. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

The KOMA-Scripts introduce a number of different document styles (usually starting with the letters "scr") which change some of the layouts of your document. Most notably you will see that section/chapter titles are no longer written in a serif typeface but in the default sans-serif typeface.

It also includes options to further specify the layout such as per-page headers and footers as well as commands to control which header/footer elements are displayed where.

It may well be that KOMA also introduces more commands to control the layout in other areas -- I do not know.