# Presentations best style

Tags: presentations

What is the best package/style to build a presentation? I use PDFSLID. Any better?

Comment: It may depend on what are you trying to achieve. You may want to edit your question to include more details. As you mention package/style, I assume you use LaTeX. I have very good experiences with beamer (latex-beamer.sf.net). There are also some very nice options for presentations in ConTeXt.

Comment: @Jan: Perhaps you can add an answer with some context links?

Comment: Thank you Jan. I pretend to use it, as I do now, for my classes presentations at the University. I teach numerical methods for Electrical Engineering. I use LaTex (actually PDFLaTeX).

Comment: Thank you again Jan.
I can send you a PDF presentation, as an axample, if you give me some address or site where I might upload it. Sorry, it is in spanish although the layout is the same for many of them.

Answer (score 21):

My favorite (so far, I haven't tried them all) is beamer.

[Beamer page on CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer)

[Beamer homepage on github](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer)

There are lots of beautiful templates you can choose from and it's very customizable. It also seems to be widely used so you can find help online.

Comment: I prefer beamer too. Here's a theme gallery: http://mike.depalatis.net/beamerthemes/ Note, you could additionaly choose different color themes and there are more themes available.

Answer (score 8):

Though [beamer](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) is my favorite, I would like to mention the `powerdot` class.

- [Package on CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/powerdot)
- [powerdot manual](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/powerdot/doc/powerdot.pdf)

It is the successor of [`prosper`](http://ctan.org/pkg/prosper) and [`HA-prosper`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ha-prosper) class resp. package. It offers a LyX layout file.

powerdot requires PSTricks. As I already mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/782/what-are-the-available-documentclass-types-and-their-uses), it offers many styles and allows creating your own style, further it provides automatic overlays and a handout mode.

Some demonstration files for a quick impression:

- [Compiled examples](http://stuwww.uvt.nl/~hendri/) from the documentation
- A [thesis defence](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~ynagel/tex/defense.pdf) ([source](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~ynagel/tex/defense.zip))
- [A research talk](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~ynagel/tex/GPStalk.pdf)
- [Presentation](http://www.siart.de/typografie/powerdot_20060207.pdf) and powerdot demo by Uwe Siart
- The nice [Jena style](http://www.personal.uni-jena.de/~xcr/v2/Dateien/File/neu-powerdot-jena/demo-powerdotJena.pdf) (btw. I've studied there :-)

Finally, here's a very nice overview by Michael Wiedmann: [**Screen Presentation Tools**](http://www.miwie.org/presentations/presentations.html). It compares packages like beamer, prosper, slides, powerdot and many more.

Comment: Thank you Stefan for your kindness and complete response. I will start inmediately.

Comment: 'Compiled examples' link seems to be dead :/

Answer (score 6):

Responding to a request for an answer with ConTeXt links: probably the most useful would be 
[this page on ConTeXtGarden](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Presentations). You can also look at some [examples of ConTeXt presentations](http://www.pragma-ade.com/show-exa-1.htm) at the pragma web site.

Answer (score 1):

I use `beamer`. It has a good documentation, which can be found in [the CTAN archive](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf).