# Which package to use for presentations? Beamer, Prosper, or Other

Tags: beamer, presentations, powerdot

I have to prepare my slides in latex. A quick search came up with different packages. Before start preparing, I need your experiences. I do not want to regret after learning one as I did, learning vim (now can not quit) instead of emacs.

EDIT:
After asking this question at that time, I start learning Beamer. Now I'm really happy with that, I created my own template and now it's easier just copying from my .tex files to beamer template. I recommend beamer for powerpoint users who are actively using latex .

Comment: Fair question, but just a side note, why do you seem to "regret" learning vim instead of emacs? Would be interested to hear your thoughts on it. From what I see many people seem to believe in the reverse, especially under current development environment. Also I don't see why you can't also just pick up another one even after you've learned its alternative at first.

Comment: @JIXiang fyiw I also agree on this. Vim might have a steeper learning curve but eventually it pays off and is a far more versatile editor than emacs.

Comment: @buttercookie Well actually that comment was made 2 years ago. Now I'm using Spacemacs which is a kind of a hybrid between Emacs and Vim. Emacs is indeed much more powerful generally, and I get to preserve all Vim keybindings and operations. I never looked back. You may also want to check it out if you're interested https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/

Comment: ouch, knocked on the wrong door on this one :). I consider myself a hardcore vim user so I'll have to disagree, though I will take a look at spacemacs

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I highly recommend the `beamer` class.

Here are features of presentation classes intended to help you deciding:

- [beamer](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) provides a huge amount of features, a lot of themes and sophisticated ways for customization. It offers an outstanding comprehensive [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf). It can be used with LaTeX and also with pdfLaTeX. So it's capable of using pdfLaTeX microtypographic features, and furthermore it supports PNG, JPEG and PDF image formats besides EPS. It uses pgf for graphics.
- [powerdot](https://ctan.org/pkg/powerdot) cannot be used with pdfLaTeX. It uses PSTricks for graphics and supports EPS images. So, it may be a good choice for a PSTricks user who doesn't need direct JPEG, PNG or PDF image support. It also provides templates, further it offers a LyX style file.
- [prosper](https://ctan.org/pkg/prosper) is older. Its successor is [HA-Prosper](https://ctan.org/pkg/ha-prosper). powerdot has been built on it, so I would not use prosper any more.

There are further and even older classes, such as `seminar` and `slides`; the latter is a standard LaTeX2e class.

See also the answers to:

- [Are there alternatives to Beamer for slides?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15198/are-there-alternatives-to-beamer-for-slides)
- [Presentations best style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2264/presentations-best-style)

Comment: prosper is really outdated and shouldn't be mentioned anymore

Comment: Can powerdot be used with `xelatex`?

Comment: @Matthew: I've read that `powerdot` works with `xelatex`, though there might be problems since `powerdot` uses dvips specials.

Comment: thanks for great comments as usual. i have no doubts to start learning beamer now.

Comment: Frankly in terms of provided themes I'd say that powerdot offers greater variety and more pleasing to the eye visuals. The themes for beamer look old-school and pretty similar to each other.

Comment: @rbaleksandar There are a lot of community contributed independent beamer themes.

Comment: So does powerdot. :) I was just comparing the shipped themes when you install beamer or powerdot.

Answer (score 23):

I do not have a basis of comparison as I've used nothing else (except for SliTeX back in the day), but I have to say that [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) is phenomenal.

Its templating, font, and color selection mechanism make it infinitely customizable, and the overlay mechanisms allows slideshows to be really dynamic.  I've never regretted learning it.

Comment: Indeed. I have never regretted it either and it is also priceless to see PowerPoint people's impressed facial expressions when they see Beamer in action. I have not found a better option to date.

Comment: I mostly agree, though "inifintely customizable" is a bit exaggerated.  See e.g. http://mbork.pl/2010-11-17_Changing_the_color_of_theorems_in_beamer_%28en%29

Comment: @mbork: I didn't say all customizations were easy! `:-D` Just when you think you know enough LaTeX you find some task which requires you to learn a little more...

Answer (score 12):

My approach is not really LaTeX-specific (it's not a package), but I'm posting it for the record. It's also very minimalistic.

For small presentations, or urgent ones, you can go with **[pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc) export to [Slidy](http://www.w3.org/Talks/Tools/Slidy/)**, for example (pandoc also exports to [S5](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/s5/) and [DZSlides](http://paulrouget.com/dzslides/)). you can write a simple document with the `article` class and run `pandoc` in it.

Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\author{A. Author}
\title{Lorem ipsum}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Lorem}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec convallis, neque a scelerisque ultricies, urna metus ultricies ligula, eu sagittis dolor est non dolor. Nunc vestibulum hendrerit urna, convallis egestas diam interdum sit amet.
\section{Lists}
You can make lists:
\begin{itemize}
\item Lorem
\item Ipsum
\item sit dolor
\item amet
\end{itemize}
\section{Numbered Lists}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Lorem
\item Ipsum
\item sit dolor
\item amet
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

And then run

```
pandoc --self-contained --to=slidy <latex file>.tex --output=<slidy file>.html
```

And you get a very, very simple presentation in a few minutes. The bad side is you'll have to rely on your presentation contents and your oratory skills: it's *not* [“so convincing that your audience will believe everything”](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/) (I'm sorry, but that just sounds too comic to me)

Answer (score 8):

Lets try to be little bit less partisan (I know that many people on this forum are GAGA about TikZ/PGF library which is fantastic) and give some more balanced point of view.

There are several classes (I do not mean here LaTeX classes) of presentation tools but classes as in browser based, PDF based, DVI based, Python based etc...

Here is semi-comprehensive list [of presentation tools](http://www.miwie.org/presentations/presentations.html) with not such great reviews (for obvious reason a single or even several human beings would have very hard time to be familiar with such plethora of tools).

Now within PDF (LaTeX based of course) class of tools there is almost no contest IMHO.

Powerdot 47 pages user manual (you need to read no more than 10), easily customization well playing with [impressive](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/) small but active user community. Based on PSTricks its original LaTeX class of presentations (Prosper) which is in works since early nineties.

Beamer 240 pages user manual, most presentation look the same, difficult to customize without at least some knowledge of TikZ, huge user community. In works for much shorter time than PSTricks and based on the proprietary vendor locked data format (PDF) as oppose to a programming language.

I am going for 10 pages manual because I have more important things to do before I deliver that "important" conference talk instead fighting 240 pages of Beamer manual.

**Edit:**

Sorry for the slow response guys. I am on a scuba diving trip down at
Florida Keys with my kids so this is the first time this week that I am
in front of the computer. I would like in this edit to summarize my
respond to concerns expressed in the comments.

My original post was meant to present a different point of view but
never intended to be too serious. I will tell you what I really think
about presentation tools.

1- The most first most important thing in any presentation is the content of the presentation.

2- The second most important thing in any presentation is the content of 
the presentation

. . .

1000- The thousandth most important thing in any presentation is the content of the presentation.

Now as of tools my advice to any casual (means you are not paid to use TeX per se) user is to apply principle of the least effort+consistency. Some of the best lectures I have seen in my life have been given with black board and chalk.
As a matter of fact most mathematician of older generation I met have consider using overhead slides, Powerpoint, TeX and similar tools reserved only for very week mathematician who have no new results/content to report.

If you really want to use LaTeX as a presentation tool use least effort and consistency. If you are using TikZ/PGF libraries as graphing tools stick with Beamer and stay away from Powerdot.

If you are familiar with PostScript and use PSTricks then the obvious choice is Powerdot.

If you are using lots of Python to do numerical simulations chose something Python based.

Do not learn new tools just for the sake of learning it.

---

P.S. As stated on many occasions I am PostScript bias. I am consistent with it.
I use PSTricks, I use Powerdot, all my pictures are in eps format. I can even hack PostSctipt. I like the fact that PostScript is open source for practical purpose. PDF format is vendor locked. Just before this trip I had manually to hack PDF paper from the Annals of Probability in order to print it because of the image stack error with the PostScript version produced with the GhostScript. Error was due to the vendor lock implemented only in Adobe reader. Since I do not use Adobe reader (nor available on OpenBSD) I had manually to fix the PostScript to be able to print PDF document.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  Does powerdot work with pdflatex?  However: (a) beamer manual is very well-organized, and you actually dan only read an 8-page tutorial (chapter 3); moreover, (b) chapter 5 (9 pages) is an excellent general guide to creating presentations.

Comment: I don't think that Stefan's answer is particularly partisan. But the simple fact is that there are really only two viable TeX packages for presentations, one (Powerdot) requires `latex+dvips` (which most people don't use anymore) and the other (Beamer) can be used with any engine. Also, the Beamer manual has an 8 page tutorial, which is probably all you need to get a presentation up and running.

Comment: @AlanMunn: agreed.  However, after a short glance at powerdot's manual, I expect that it might be easier to make one's own "theme" in it.  So it might be worth remembering.  (And it has a distinct look, which is important in the world bored by similar beamer presentations...;))

Comment: This is partisan, and also misleading.  PDF is an ISO standard and so open, not "proprietary vendor locked".  I learnt beamer in a single weekend, and customisation is really easy:change a few colours and it looks very different. (Hilarious that "They all look the same" is being used as an argument not to use something.)

Comment: Seriously, what are you saying here? Stefan has already mentioned powerdot and that it is based on pstricks.  So your new information is about the manuals, the userbase, and the age.  None of those is really a deal-breaker.  What I'd rather you said is something that powerdot can do or can easily do that beamer can't or finds hard.  That would be worth knowing.

Comment: Supporting @AndrewStacey's comment; TeXLive only includes packages usable with fully open software, and includes Beamer: See http://www.texdev.net/2012/03/27/the-tex-live-inclusion-policy/ for a discussion on PDF as an open format. Also, while you can be pretty vendor locked while an ISO standard (docx) there are multiple implementations of PDF (xpdf, SumatraPDF, foxit) meaning you can view PDFs on a computer with 0 adobe products installed. Just trying to clarify things.

Comment: OK! I don't know what Lady Gaga is using which is probably Plain TeX/Metapost directly. However please don't consider downvoting based on disagreement as we had a spree lately. As always, in case of confusion, upvote!

Comment: Could you support your statement the `powerdot` allows "easily [sic] customization" with some explanation? I found section 9, "Creating your own style", in [the manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/powerdot), which offers a lot of lengths and colors to be tweaked. While this may be more helpful than the `beamer` manual when it comes to adjustments of this kind, I can't really see how these parameters can substantially change the look of a presentation so that not "most presentation look the same" as `beamer` presentations do in your opinion.

Comment: Hello.  If I want to create a pdf with animations, do you advise to do it with Knitr+animation package or with Beamer?  I know a little bit of Latex.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer OpTeX with `\slides` in the preamble. It is much more simple than beamer, the source code is more readable and transparent. See [OpTeX slides](http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/op-slides.pdf) for more details. I have a lot of positive feedback from OpTeX users.

Comment: Can we use LaTeX packages with OpTeX, such as `pgfplots`?

Comment: @AlexG Yes, TikZ macros are almost format independent. Use syntax as documented for plain TeX. For example pgfplots documentation, the bottom of the page 39.

Comment: Transcribing notes to OpTeX slides is straightforward, a relief for typists. It's clean and simple. It flows to the next page if you fill up the page with text. After years of using `beamer`, I won't go back. And yes, all the colored boxes available in `beamer` can be done, and other stuff is much more easily configurable.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer Beamer.

Yes, the learning curve is intense and I am just having a few weeks of experience right now. However, as soon as you start re-using stuff, you start winning --- and I am feeling that already. That 240 page manual also clearly tells you that you can adapt to any possible scenario that you might have, now and in the future, so it will stay faithfully with you, whatever you want to do. For me it is very important that I can do everything with a tool in one area and I do not need to learn 2 or 3 tools and switch in between them. That is more confusing.

I have access to 2-3 good templates (all mainstream ones are basically dead-boring and look terrible) and I enjoy adapting them and then it is manageable and fun.

Comment: Just curiosity, which 2-3 good templates?

Comment: http://kaszkowiak.eu/wronki-a-new-beamer-template/#prettyphoto[group]/9/ This one has potential. I am adapting it right now into a few directions to make it more printer friendly and with better fonts that are easier to read. Given that I am am not very experienced in adapting Latex templates (or any kind) and still can manage this OK, I assume this should be a good and easy playground for a lot of people :) Its really nice...

Comment: Did you finish your work adapting wronki theme? Could you share it?

Comment: Wronki template has been moved to: https://github.com/kangur85/wronki