# \subtitle doesn't work in article document class

Tags: titles, document-classes, article

I'm relatively new to TeX but until now I used mostly the `beamer` class. There I did this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
  \title{title}
  \subtitle{subtitle}
  \author{name}
  \date{\today}
\begin{document}
    %content
\end{document}
```

And it worked as I would expect but when I use the `article` class the subtitle does not work.

So it seems that a) I got something wrong or b) it's not the right document class. So I ask you guys:

**How do I use a subtitle in the article class?**

or

Which document class should I use for my document? I'm attempting to write a document with 50 to 100 pages. It will be a documentation for a programming project so it will contain code snippets and diagrams.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

If you used `scrartcl` instead of `article`, the command `\subtitle` would immediately work as expected. `scrartcl` belongs to the KOMA-Script classes which are extended replacements of the LaTeX standard classes. I strongly recommend KOMA-Script. For reasons have a look at:

- [Most useful additions in KOMA-Script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1351/most-useful-additions-in-koma-script)

Your document is considerably large. An `article`-like class may be ok (`scrartcl`), but if you need a chapter-like sectioning you could consider to use `report` (or `scrreprt`, which is a KOMA class).

You might be interested in the answers to this question:

- [What are your favorite document classes and what do you use them for?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4221/what-are-your-favorite-document-classes-and-what-do-you-use-them-for)
- [What are the available “documentclass” types and their uses?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/782/what-are-the-available-documentclass-types-and-their-uses)

Comment: note that `\maketitle` makes both the title and subtitle when `scrartcl` is used.  (no call to something like `\makesubtitle` is needed.)

Answer (score 92):

To supplement Stefan's answer, the core LaTeX `article` class does not have a `\subtitle` macro. You can therefore either do something like

```
\title{Title \\ Subtitle}
```

or consider the `titlepage` environment. Other document classes, notably KOMA-Script, do have a separate `\subtitle` macro available.

Comment: Isn't in normal for the subtitle to be slightly smaller than the title. So if the title were `\Large` the command might be supplemented: `\title{Title \\ \large Subtitle}`

Comment: @Seamus: This would depend on exactly how the 'subtitle' is intended to look, but you are right that this is often the case. I'd probably go for the `titlepage` environment to do this.

Comment: @JosephWright How can I use the `titlepage` environment to do this? Can you explain?

Comment: @becko http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280

Answer (score 12):

A fully adapted possibility for the subtitle generation in the *document class* `article` includes reducing the fontsize in the subtitle, as @Seamus mentioned above, but relatively (!), and increasing the distance between title and subtitle.
Therefore my suggestion is following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}

\title{Experimental Test\\[0.2em]\smaller{}Stimuli generation}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    My document
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want a "fully" adaptable title: relative size and line separation can be adapted

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}


\newcommand{\subtitlerelsize}{1} %relative size: integer value
\newcommand{\subtitlelinesep}{0.2em} %line separation: a LaTeX length

\title{Experimental Test\\[\subtitlelinesep]%
    \smaller[\subtitlerelsize]{}Stimuli generation}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    My document
\end{document}
```