# Trying to add a subtitle to the main title of my document but it's not working

Tags: titles

This is what I have been previously told to use by uni for essays written in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{a4-mancs}
\usepackage{pslatex}
```

Based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5948/subtitle-doesnt-work-in-article-document-class) question and others I've found I've changed `article` to `scrartcl`.

Then:

```
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
  \title{Standardising Software}
  \subtitle{An update on the article 'The welcome demise of style' from the Economist, September 1989\cite{the welcome demise of style}}
  \author{me}
\maketitle

\newpage
...
```

However this doesn't work - when I run `latex essay.tex` it says the subtitle bit is an `undefined control sequence`, and it comes out with the subtitle on its own on the first page of the document.

Comment: This code works for me with `scrartcl`. Which version of KOMA-Script are you using? Perhaps update. Or show a real MWE.

Comment: So it's probably the uni's set up then? To submit the essay I run a command on the uni computers which compiles it and sends it off so it has to be compatible with whatever they've installed.

Comment: @zephyrdragon: Well, we'd have to know whatever your university's set-up is. It might also be helpful if you expanded your code to a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), starting with `\documentclas{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @doncherry I don't know how to find out what the university's set up is though. And from that link I've put everything that would be in a MWE apart from `\end{document}`, I think?

Comment: One of my coursemates has told me he's using `\title{TITLE \vspace{1em}\\\normalsize{SUBTITLE}}`, so I'm using that. Thanks for all your help.