# Subtitle in IEEE document class

Tags: ieeetran

How can I add a subtitle to my Latex document using the IEEETran document class?

I would like to know if it is possible to use a built-in command that gives me the regular title in addition to a subtitle written in a slightly smaller font?

I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5948/subtitle-doesnt-work-in-article-document-class) related to it, where they recommend to use a title page, but this does not seem to fit my needs. Also, I looked in [the documentation for the IEEETran class](http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~sle841/papers/Arch_TVCG/misc/tex%20files/original_tvcg_files/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) but was unable to find it there.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384)

Comment: There is no built in command for a subtitle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\title{A clever paper \\ {\large really clever}}
\author{A Person}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know if this is allowed (when submitting a paper following the IEEE doc. class)?

Comment: It depends on the journal, but I would say almost certainly not. If the class does not provide for subtitles, they are probably not allowed.

Comment: @kfuglsang `ieeetran` style is not conclusive but only suggestive; whatever you do with your file it will be reprocessed by the copy editor using their internal style. The publication office will turn your subtitle concatenated to the title after a colon. Something like **Matrix : The movie not the square thingy**.

Comment: I've read conference call for paper documents that say something like "use IEEETran and follow the margin guidelines, but prepare a document that expresses your work as you see fit". In these cases i think one can take such liberties.