# How to set maintitle and subtitle?

Tags: titles

Recently, I have been translating a foreign paper that has main title and subtitle.

My trial:

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm}
\begin{document}
\title{
 Simulatin Modelling Practice and Theoty \\ 
\begin{large} 
  Common Simulation of a SCARA robot with PD and learning controller
\end{large} }

\end{document}
```

However, it failed to achieve that effect.
The main title is *Simulatin Modelling Practice and Theory*, subtitle is »Simulation of a SCARA robot with PD and learning controller«. So my question is how to alter it?

Comment: What's the real problem? With ``\title{First line\\\large Second line}`` I get what seems a good result.

Comment: @egreg,I think the OP wonder wethear use the latex command like `\subtitle `,however,the latex doesn't own that command.

Comment: @tangshutao There is no such command in the `ctexart` class.

Comment: You don’t say whether you have to keep using ctex for the translated article. In a [similar, previous answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5948/subtitle-doesnt-work-in-article-document-class) KOMA Script classes are recommended, which I second.

Comment: Also `paper` document class have a `\subtitle{}` command.

Comment: @egreg Want to write up an answer?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

I have no problem if I use `\large` instead of the non existent `large` environment.

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm}
\begin{document}

\title{%
  Simulating Modelling Practice and Theory \\
  \large Common Simulation of a SCARA robot \\
    with PD and learning controller}

\author{Shutao Tang}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This usage of 'inexistent' is possibly deprecated (OED), and the word is now used with another meaning. I think you want 'non-existent'? ['Inexistent' apparently means 'Existing or having its being in something else; inherent.' 'Inexistent' was, it seems, used to mean 'non-existent' in the seventeenth and eighteenth centuries. OED have '? Obs' which I assume means that they aren't certain this usage is deprecated, but they think it probably is.]

Comment: @cfr False friends!

Comment: Nadolig llawen!

Comment: For me it is giving error like,  File `ctexart.cls' not found. \usepackage

Comment: @David You have an incomplete TeX installation. Note that the answer is not specific for the `ctexart` class.

Comment: How do you get the spacing between the title and the subtitle right?

Comment: @layser Use ``\\[2ex]`` or whatever length you deem appropriate.

Answer (score 17):

I tried with the class article..it is giving nicely..

The codes are here..

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}
\begin{document}

\title{%
  Simulating Modelling Practice and Theory \\
  \large Common Simulation of a SCARA robot \\
    with PD and learning controller}

\author{Shutao Tang}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]