# What is the advantage of using minimal over article when creating a standalone graphic?

Tags: document-classes, article, minimal

What is the advantage of using `minimal` document class over `article` document class when creating a standalone graphic?

---

Bonus question:

Before I have time to make a test by myself, is there anybody here know whether `minimal` will compile faster than `article`?

Comment: Good question. I have just been using the `standalone` class since it was specifically created for use in standalone graphics.

Comment: @Peter, @all: Note that the `standalone` class (written by me) uses the `article` class internally. As Stefan points out `minimal` doesn't define some font related macros like the fonts size commands so it is not really useful for standalone drawings. However, any other class can be used using the `class=<class name>` as class option for `standalone` class.

Comment: @Martin: The wildcard `@all` really works?

Comment: @xport: No, it is just an indicator to show that I also want to address the general public.

Comment: @Martin: standalone is my favorite package ever  :)

Comment: Thanks @Vivi, I planning to release v1.0 soon which will have some nice new features.

Comment: People interested in this question might also want to read the answers to [If you know errors occurred in article & minimal, which one will you use for the subsequent attempts in troubleshooting?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23175/2552)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

- The `minimal` class has already `empty` page style, so no page number is printed. There's no page number needed for a standalone graphic.
- `minimal` doesn't define macros. There's less than in `article` which could disturb.

However, usually I would use `minimal` just for testing or for showing a minimal working example. Though for just displaying a graphic it might be sufficient.

For creating graphics you might miss features which are provided by other base classes. Just some examples, important if you create graphics with text:

- You cannot use common font size commands such as `\small` and `\large`, they are undefined. `minimal` uses a 10pt font.
- Obsolete LaTeX 2.09 commands such as `\bf` and `\it` are still supported in `article`, but not in `minimal`.

Comment: I agree. Also I personally don't see `minimal` as a real class, e.g. because of the missing font size commands and missing length settings. A minimal example which uses the `minimal` class might show different results as a real class so it should be avoided. IMHO `minimal` is just a "hello world" class.

Comment: @Martin: I disagree. When using tikZ or pstricks without having text, it really makes sense to use the minimal class instead of another one.

Comment: @Herbert: If you don't have any text, then maybe yes. I normally have some text in my diagram and then I often want to use different sizes. Is there a drawback of `article` in the no-text case?

Comment: @Martin: I am talking about minimal examples and not regular diagrams. For minimal examples where users want to find a problem, it is easier to use the `minimal` class, because the filelist is then realy short.

Comment: I am not sure I would see the lack of high level font size commands as a big problem. In the setting discussed here, I'd like to have complete control over font sizes anyhow, so I'd just use the various font selection commands directly.

Comment: @Harald: The absence of the high level font size commands is a big impact on user-friendliness. Of course if you know how to do it then you don't need them. I personally don't know much about the internal font commands, and I'm sure beginners would be totally lost here. I still fail to see the benefit of using `minimal` in a document with text.

Comment: Another (in my opinion big) problem with `minimal` is that it doesn't assign values to `\arraycolsep`, `\tabcolsep`, `\arrayrulewidth`, `\doublerulesep`, `\fboxsep`, `\fboxrule` so standard environments such as `tabular` and `array` won't behave as expected in a class such as `article` (no separation between columns, no rules, for example).

Comment: @Martin: You wouldn't need anything other than `\fontsize` and `\selectfont`. `\textbf` and friends would still work. But I agree that it's hard to see a big benefit; all I'm saying is that the downside seems minimal (pun intended) to me.

Comment: @Herbert, @Harald: Jake also does not recommend me to use `minimal` here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4221/what-are-your-favorite-document-classes-and-what-do-you-use-them-for/6446#6446.

Comment: @xport: for minimal examples it makes sense when you do not need all the other features of the the standard classes.

Answer (score 24):

that is all, what `minimal` defines:

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}   
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8in}
\pagenumbering{arabic}  % but no page numbers are printed because:
\pagestyle{empty}       % this is actually already in the kernel
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `minimal` is simpler than using `article` for creating a graphics with a tight paper size.

```
\documentclass{minimal}%\documentclass{article}
%\pagestyle{empty}
%\headheight=0pt
%\headsep=0pt
\usepackage{pstricks}
\paperwidth=72.27pt
\paperheight=72.27pt
\topmargin=-72.27pt
\oddsidemargin=-72.27pt
\parindent=0sp
\special{papersize=\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(\paperwidth,\paperheight)
\psframe[linecolor=red](\paperwidth,\paperheight)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```