# If you know errors occurred in article & minimal, which one will you use for the subsequent attempts in troubleshooting?

Tags: document-classes, article, minimal

Assume that

> For the first and second investigation you know errors occurred when
>   using article and minimal.

Which one will you use for the subsequent investigation, `article` or `minimal`?

Answer (score 13):

Using the `minimal` class instead of `article` **introduces** errors and does not remove them. There is nothing in `article` which can add to your problems. However there are many things missing in `minimal` which packages and the user normally awaits! I once used it for a table related MWS (minimum working solution :-) ) which first didn't worked. It took me 15 minutes to figure that it happened because one skip register was still not initialized and still zero! Changing to `article` fixed it then.

There is **NO REASON** to use `minimal` IMHO. It's not a real class! It was not created as a class for *minimal* working examples, even if the name might suggest that. You don't gain anything non-trivial from using it instead of `article`. It might not make any difference for your MWE but might be for the solution of the very same.

Comment: Indeed, `minimal` reflects the way LaTeX had to work 20 years ago on very different computer hardware. _The_ standard test class is `article`.

Comment: (It is a flaw in the way LaTeX2e is set up that some the base macros for logical structure are defined in classes and not in the kernel. This is to be regretted!)

Comment: The lack of features provided by `article` in `minimal` may be the source of problem. But the extra features in `article` may also be the source of problem. Is my hypothesis logically correct? However in this question, I assumed that errors occurred in `article` and `minimal`. So what is your strategy for your subsequent attempt in troubleshooting?

Comment: `minimal` is _not a proper LaTeX2e class_. `article` is the _minimum_ you need to properly define a LaTeX2e class: it does not 'add any features'!

Comment: @Joseph is this base macros being not in the kernel something LaTeX3 will solve?

Comment: @Martin: Quoting your statement in the first paragraph "There is nothing in article which can add to your problems. ". Is there a situation where using article instead of minimal results in an error?

Answer (score 7):

If an error happens only with `minimal` I wouldn't care. `minimal` is often simply to minimal.

If an error happens only with `article` I would continue the investigation with article, but keep the information that something different happens with minimal in the back of my mind.

Comment: If errors happens in both `minimal` and `article`, will you continue the investigation with `minimal`?

Comment: In article. There are less side-effects than with the incomplete minimal.