# how to add a label to a path?

Tags: tikz-pgf

For example (used by another thread):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.5cm, grow=down,
    every node/.style={draw, circle, thin},
    edge from parent/.style={-latex, thick, draw}
]
\node (P) {P}
    child {node (Q) {Q}
        child {node (T) {T}}
        child {node (U) {U}}
    }
    child {node (R) {R}}
    child {node (S) {S}};

\path (P) -- coordinate[midway] (PQ) (Q);
\path (P) -- coordinate[midway] (PR) (R);

\draw (PQ) to[bend right=22] (PR);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

how can I add a label, e.g., `M` to the line `PQ`?

Comment: Never use the `minimal` class. It exists for very different purposes than preparing examples.

Comment: See [Herbert's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20976/5764) in [What is the advantage of using `minimal` over `article` when creating a standalone graphic?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20974/5764) `minimal` doesn't define everything you always wanted. It may work in this instance, but it's not always transferable to other minimal examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Putting the label is easy by using another node. The problem is, with the `draw` to `every node` style, all of your nodes are drawn as circles, which I think you do not want for the node with the label `M`. You can use `scope` inside your `tikzpicture` to separate the styles as I did here.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[level distance=1.5cm, grow=down,
    every node/.style={draw, circle, thin},
    edge from parent/.style={-latex, thick, draw}
]
\node (P) {P}
    child {node (Q) {Q}
        child {node (T) {T}}
        child {node (U) {U}}
    }
    child {node (R) {R}}
    child {node (S) {S}};

\path (P) -- coordinate[midway] (PQ) (Q);
\path (P) -- coordinate[midway] (PR) (R);

\draw (PQ) to[bend right=22] (PR);
\end{scope}

\node [above left] at (PQ) {M}; % Draws the node labeled M

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since the [release of pgf/TikZ 3.0](http://latex-community.org/home/news/84-news-latex-graphics-figures-tables/491-tikz-pgf-30) it's easier to label edges, using the `quotes` syntax. If you already got an edge, it could be as simple as adding "text" to the edge option. Here, let's make it after the tree is drawn:

```
\path (P) edge["M"'] (Q);
```

Your bend line looks like an angle. With the also new `angles` library, you could add

```
pic[draw,angle radius=0.8cm] {angle=Q--P--R}
```

to the path above, for this. Now you don't even need to define coordinates (PQ) and (PR). Also the bend line is more like a radius, not just a connection between midpoints.

A complete code, modifying the suggestion by hpesoj626:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,quotes,angles}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[level distance=1.5cm, grow=down,
    every node/.style={draw, circle, thin},
    edge from parent/.style={-latex, thick, draw}
  ]
  \node (P) {P}
    child {node (Q) {Q}
        child {node (T) {T}}
        child {node (U) {U}}
    }
    child {node (R) {R}}
    child {node (S) {S}};
  \end{scope}
  \path (P) edge["M"'] (Q) pic[draw,angle radius=0.8cm] {angle=Q--P--R};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: labeled edges and angle]