# Very consistent latex - customized class or KOMA?

Tags: floats, koma-script, document-classes

This is mostly a thought exercise, but in working on a large document,
I've come across some annoying inconsistencies when working with latex. These are usually somewhat trivially fixed, but they add up over time and it's kind of a mess, though it's a little better when they are in their own style files.

For example, when adding custom floats with the `float` package and then requesting the listofXXXX, the line in the toc doesn't have a vspace, whereas
for figures and tables it does (the `report.cls` file adds it, but it is not customizable). Then the list of listings from the `listings` package may look a bit different.

There are some other examples, but the overall story is that after a while the document becomes a mishmash of stuff handled by the class and many add-on packages.

Lets say I wanted to create a large, complex document or book with lots of customization (think science - different kinds of equations, figures, schemes, examples, problems, etc), with a VERY consistent but somewhat non-standard (by latex standards) layout. How might this be done?

I see maybe 2 possibilities:

1. KOMA or similar (feel free to mention others)
2. Some sort of class (like `minimal`) that does the bare minimum, then allow the packages to control everything

Or maybe something more powerful than latex?

Comment: If you want lost of customization, maybe you need your own .cls file.

Comment: +1 for writing your own `.cls` file; see [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34175/how-do-i-create-a-latex-package]. I'd suggest documenting it, as well – I did that for my lecture notes this year, and it was really useful for keeping track of which custom commands did what.

Comment: the `minimal` documentclass may not be a good starting point; the addon packages would have to reimplement even the most basic features of a class, because it's so minimal.

Comment: Regarding `minimal`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20974/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-minimal-over-article-when-creating-a-standalone-g

Comment: I'd probably create my own class for a project like this that wraps around a KOMA class so I could take advantage of many features KOMA brings. Regarding the`float` package: the `caption` bundle including its `newfloat` package surely is a better alternative. When using a KOMA-Script class there is a built-in possibility for defining new float types so that neither `float` nor `newfloat` are needed.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I did read that about `minimal`, but I just meant something similar to that. Currently, I'm using my own `.cls` file based on `report`, but I was just wondering if that is proper or if maybe KOMA would be a more flexible starting point

Comment: Though I’m an active Koma-Script user: What’s with `memoir`?