# Easiest way to draw diagrams like this in a LaTeX document?

Tags: graphics

I'd like to produce diagrams such as this:

[image]

It is purely illustrative. There are no numbers attached to any of the points.

What is the simplest way for me to generate diagrams like this for a LaTeX document? TikZ, or pgfplot, or metapost or something else?

Comment: Use `pgfplots` with a fake function and fake slopes.

Comment: ...there is no "best" way.

Comment: You also can try `pstricks-add` which defines commands for plotting tangent lines and normal to curves.

Comment: A lot of people take exception to questions of the form "Please draw this for me". You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a minimal working example.

Comment: Easiest? Easiest is `\includegraphics{}`... assuming you have access to a copy of the desired image. Why do you want to *draw* it in LaTeX itself? Draw-in-LaTeX does not really go with Easiest.

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you what's the simplest way for *me*.

I use Inkscape to do the drawings and export as pstricks (Save As: "Latex + pstricks macros"). It took me ~5 mins to do the drawing. Everything in the `mydiagram` definition is generated by Inkscape.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\newcommand*{\mydiagram}{%
    \psset{xunit=.5pt,yunit=.5pt,runit=.5pt}
    \begin{pspicture}(330.50705617,288.43274454)
    {
        \newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
        \pscustom[linewidth=1,linecolor=curcolor]
        {
            \newpath
            \moveto(0.5,288.43274454)
            \lineto(0.5,0.5)
            \lineto(330.50704768,0.5)
        }
    }
    {
        \newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
        \pscustom[linewidth=1,linecolor=curcolor]
        {
            \newpath
            \moveto(0.5,45.12426565)
            \lineto(130.01750712,186.28944553)
        }
    }
    {
        \newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
        \pscustom[linewidth=1,linecolor=curcolor]
        {
            \newpath
            \moveto(183.90275326,222.02202485)
            \lineto(325.51339417,272.5714033)
        }
    }
    {
        \newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
        \pscustom[linewidth=1,linecolor=curcolor]
        {
            \newpath
            \moveto(93.08775773,119.42213388)
            \curveto(97.50632542,132.2702716)(105.27221632,159.17255412)(127.77442721,183.87039437)
            \curveto(140.87266571,198.24672499)(158.1196668,212.82204774)(183.90275326,222.02202485)
            \curveto(193.19893824,225.33911657)(203.60481614,227.95741498)(215.32600504,229.61564371)
        }
    }
    {
        \newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
        \pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
        {
            \newpath
            \moveto(216.93720724,229.72948325)
            \curveto(216.93720724,228.79708086)(216.18134576,228.04121938)(215.24894338,228.04121938)
            \curveto(214.31654099,228.04121938)(213.56067951,228.79708086)(213.56067951,229.72948325)
            \curveto(213.56067951,230.66188564)(214.31654099,231.41774712)(215.24894338,231.41774712)
            \curveto(216.18134576,231.41774712)(216.93720724,230.66188564)(216.93720724,229.72948325)
            \closepath
        }
    }
    {
        \newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
        \pscustom[linewidth=1,linecolor=curcolor,linestyle=dashed,dash=5 5]
        {
            \newpath
            \moveto(130.01750712,186.28944553)
            \lineto(200.77793033,263.46440965)
        }
    }
    {
        \newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
        \pscustom[linewidth=1,linecolor=curcolor,linestyle=dashed,dash=5 5]
        {
            \newpath
            \moveto(0.5,156.54830295)
            \lineto(183.90275326,222.02202485)
        }
    }
    \end{pspicture} %
}

\begin{document}
    \mydiagram
\end{document}
```

[image: mydiagram]

Comment: Unrelated comment: Generally, it's best to use `article` instead of `minimal`, see [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. ... unless you make a standalone graphic or just for testing - http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20974/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-minimal-over-article-when-creating-a-standalone-g

Comment: For a standalone graphic, why not use the `standalone` class? Even though Stefan says *might be sufficient*, I don't read his answer as a clear recommendation to use `minimal`, in particular because `\small`, `\large` etc. are undefined.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. There was no typesetting here, at that time I considered `minimal` class to be sufficient.

Comment: Sure. I did say *generally*, and it was also intended as information for anyone else who might see the post, and who wasn't aware of the potential issues with `minimal`. (Sorry, should probably have been more explicit about that.)

Comment: The point is that even if you know it is OK to use `minimal` in this particular case, lots of less experienced users will assume that `minimal` is suitable for minimal examples generally when it is not. So if you want to use it when testing yourself, that's no problem. But please don't use it when posting examples here as it causes entirely avoidable confusion for no benefit at all.

Comment: I edited the MWE and changed the `documentclass` from `minimal` to `article`.