# Beamer for letter size paper

Tags: beamer, paper-size

My daughter is in high school and is working on a science project.  She has really enjoyed writing the paper in LaTeX.  Now, she has to make a tri-fold presentation of the major points.  In the past, that has meant PowerPoint printed onto letter-size paper then pasting those pages (one slide per page) onto the board.  How can we resize beamer to have at least the same aspect ratio as letter-size paper?  Ideally, we would have the same dimensions, also, but that is not so important as we can scale at print time.  I have used `beamerposter` in the past, but that generates just one page, I think.  Any suggestions are appreciated.  The default is to simply use `beamer` as-is and scale to as close to letter size as possible when printing.

Comment: Perhaps http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16355/19384 can be of use.

Comment: If you want those fancy color and box stuff provided by `beamer`, [beamerposter](http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/latexbeamerposter.php) is the right choice. If you want something less fancy, just take a "default" class. Build-in  aspect ratios for `beamer` are 16:10, 160mm by 100mm; 16:9,  160mm by 90mm; 14:9,  140mm by 90mm; 5:4,125mm by 100mm; 3:2, 135mm by 90mm and of course 4:3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `beamer` class sets paper height using `geometry`, so while there isn't an interface to override the settings you can just force the issue after loading the class.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\geometry{letterpaper,landscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  Hello world
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you want the aspect ratio without the full page size then you'll need to work out the `papersize` yourself. For example, the standard `beamer` settings have a paper height of 9.6 cm and width of 12.8 cm. Keeping say the width the same we might do

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\geometry{papersize={12.80cm,9.91cm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  Hello world
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here, as I've hard-coded the sizes I don't need the `landscape` key.

Comment: Can we teak this to handle 17in. x 22in. size paper or for that matter a poster size?