# Wrong page orientation when creating flyers

Tags: leaflet

The answer [Creating flyers in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16355/creating-flyers-in-latex/51725#51725) has a complete code example illustrating how to create a flier. However when I create the PDF the page orientation is *portrait* instead of *landscape*. [image: Screen shot of PDF view of leaflet]

Here is a simplified version of the code (with filler text)

```
\documentclass[10pt,foldmark,notumble]{leaflet}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lipsum}  % this package is for creating filler text

\title{\bf LaTeX Applications Symposium}

\author{%
\Large \bf A University
}
\date{\bf April 13 -- April 15, 2012 }

\CutLine*{1}% Dotted line without scissors
\CutLine{6}%  Dotted line with scissors

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Overview} 
\lipsum[1]

Unlike previous years format of the conference is different. For the first time we have invited speakers.
\lipsum[2]

We kick off on Friday, April 13 at 4:30 pm with a single invited lecture
by the Newhouse which will be also departmental colloquium lecture
for that week at the Department of Mathematical Sciences at the University.

We finish Saturday with a conference banquet.


\section{Schedule}

\vspace{0.2cm}
{\large \bf Friday, April 13}

{\bf A nice place}

\lipsum[4-9]

\section{Hotel Info}
The Hotel for the conference is the Comfort Inn located at:
1305 Tiger Blvd.
US 123 \& 76
City, SC 1234
(Phone: (123) 456-7890).

\section{Parking}
\lipsum[6]

The price, \underline{\bf not covered by organizers}, is \$23 and should
be paid in cash upon arrival. The price does not include drinks.



\section{Registration and Financial support} 

\lipsum[8-9]

\url{http://www.somewebsite.org/}

Participants who are requesting financial support will also have to do
vendor registration required by the university as well as to submit
expense report form with receipts.

\section{Organizers}

an organizer  \url{}

a big man \url{}

\section{Tour to the countryside}
\lipsum[10-12]

\end{document}
```

The orientation is wrong as well. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result I get from compiling your code:

[image: leaflet in Okular]

This is viewed in Okular but that's not the problem since the compiled document differs in your case as well.

The first thing to check is that your distribution of TeX is sufficiently current and that you are actually using the current files.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
```

A few lines later:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/leaflet/leaflet.cls
Document Class: leaflet 2013/11/06 v1.0d LaTeX document class (JS,WaS,RN,HjG)
```

That means that the version of `leaflet` is newer than was originally installed as part of TeX Live 2013. So even if you are using TL 2013, you should check and update your installation if necessary (e.g. using `tlmgr` provided you installed TeX Live from upstream).

Comment: I use TeX Live 2013 as is and the document class is *Document Class: leaflet 2012/06/04 v1.0d LaTeX document class (JS,WaS,RN,HjG)*. So I need to upgrade the leaflet package.

Comment: tlmgr update leaflet