# Creating a document with no borders or margins

Tags: margins, minipage, geometry

I want to create a small flyer. It should be folded once and have four pages in total. Also, I need a special geometry.

So far, I am trying to achieve that using minipages. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[landscape, paperwidth=15cm, paperheight=30cm, left=0mm, top=0mm, bottom=0mm, right=0mm, margin=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}%
    \colorbox{blue!50}{\begin{minipage}[t][\paperheight][t]{0.5\paperwidth}
        FRONT COVER
    \end{minipage}}%
    \colorbox{green!50}{\begin{minipage}[t][\paperheight][t]{0.5\paperwidth}
        BACK COVER
    \end{minipage}}%
    \clearpage
    \colorbox{red!50}{\begin{minipage}[t][\paperheight][t]{0.489\paperwidth}
        INSIDE LEFT
    \end{minipage}}%
    \colorbox{black!50}{\begin{minipage}[t][\paperheight][t]{0.489\paperwidth}
        INSIDE RIGHT
    \end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

Now I have several problems with that.

1. The color boxes do not align with the page borders. Instead, there is a small white margin above of the color boxes.
2. On the first page (front/back cover), these white margins are not even of the same size.
3. On the second page (inside left/right), the boxes do not align with the right page border, either.

Clearly, using minipages is either not the right way to create such a flyer, or I misunderstood how this should be working (or both). It is important that everything aligns well for the later folding. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For 3, change `0.489\paperwidth` to `0.5\paperwidth` at both places.

Comment: oh, yes! that was a stupid leftover.. thank you.

Comment: Did you check these ? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16355/creating-flyers-in-latex

Comment: Yes, I checked leaflet, but it seems that this restricts you to two foldmarks / six pages. Otherwise, that would be exactly what I want - only with one foldmark and two pages.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one try with `tabular`s.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[landscape, paperwidth=15cm, paperheight=30cm, margin=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}%
    \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    \cellcolor{blue!50}%
    \begin{minipage}[t][\paperheight][t]{0.5\paperwidth}%
        FRONT COVER
    \end{minipage}%
    \end{tabular}%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    \cellcolor{green!50}%
    \begin{minipage}[t][\paperheight][t]{0.5\paperwidth}%
        BACK COVER
    \end{minipage}%
    \end{tabular}%
    \clearpage
    \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    \cellcolor{red!50}%
    \begin{minipage}[t][\paperheight][t]{0.5\paperwidth}%
        INSIDE LEFT
    \end{minipage}%
    \end{tabular}%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    \cellcolor{black!50}%
    \begin{minipage}[t][\paperheight][t]{0.5\paperwidth}%
       INSIDE RIGHT
    \end{minipage}%
    \end{tabular}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Some how `Inside right` and `Back cover` start after some space.

Answer (score 0):

You can position things absolutely on a page using `tikz`, and placing the text in a `node` of defined width should do the trick.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=30cm, paperheight=15cm, left=0mm, top=0mm, bottom=0mm, right=0mm, margin=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[blue!50] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north);
    \fill[green!50] (current page.south east) rectangle (current page.north);
    \node[below right,align=left,text width=0.49\paperwidth] at (current page.north west){FRONT COVER

    \lipsum[1-4]};
    \node[below right,align=left,text width=0.49\paperwidth] at (current page.north){BACK COVER};
\end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[red!50] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north);
    \fill[black!50] (current page.south east) rectangle (current page.north);
    \node[below right,align=left,text width=0.49\paperwidth] at (current page.north west){FRONT COVER};
    \node[below right,align=left,text width=0.49\paperwidth] at (current page.north){BACK COVER

    \lipsum[5-8]};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably I did not explain correctly; my concern is that the minipages are just not aligned with the page margins. Using tikz and placing the minipages on top does not help me with that.

Comment: @Jenny So you want the text to be at the very edge of the page?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's not about the text or the background, more about the concept how I get exactly all the space.