# How to change the fonts of this document?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I would like to modify the fonts used in that document which used `\usepackage{mathptmx}`. I thought it could possible using Xelatex, but I don't know to do it. This is my MWE :

```
\documentclass[10pt,foldmark,notumble]{leaflet}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\renewcommand*\foldmarkrule{.3mm}
\renewcommand*\foldmarklength{5mm}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=0.9]{helvet}
\makeatletter


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Don't use `inputenc` or `fontenc` with xetex. Use `fontspec` and then specify any opentype font you have on your system. I used one example below.

```
\documentclass[10pt,foldmark,notumble]{leaflet}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\renewcommand*\foldmarkrule{.3mm}
\renewcommand*\foldmarklength{5mm}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage[scaled=0.9]{helvet}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Comic Sans MS}

\makeatletter
\title{test}
\author{egreg}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: You copied from one of my documents!

Comment: @egreg: yes I found it here! Do you remember the link to that document ? If it's the case, I could link that post to it.

Comment: @domi :P :P :P :P

Comment: @egreg:  P-P-Platypus? I found the link: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16355/creating-flyers-in-latex/16359