# How to style like they do it in "Big Ideas Simply Explained" books?

Tags: tikz-pgf, book-design, journal-publishing

So how to structure my document so that it would look like one of [this books](https://www.penguinrandomhouse.com/series/AAY/big-ideas-simply-explained):

[image]
[image]

Features I search for are general for any modern magazine:

- 3 columns interruptable with images
- columns have a coloured line between them
- sections of pages can be 'highlights' occupying one or more columns
- columns can be temporarily joined for an image with a footnote
- one can create the horizontal lines and surround images with colour borders

How to recreate such a basic journal-style in LaTeX? May be It is somehow automatable with Tikz (tex for page source data and Tikz for layout kind of mimicking Adobe Pagemaker)?

*[Images source - amazon shop](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Psychology-Book-Ideas-Simply-Explained/dp/0756689708)*

Comment: This is actually not so easy in LaTeX. You could look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16355/87678 for some ideas. I would probably use [Scribus](http://www.scribus.net).

Comment: Another relevant post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60259/87678

Comment: Some publishing houses use to create what you want a software called [Adobe InDesign](https://www.adobe.com/products/indesign.html) to pay. They also use LaTeX, have installed the fonts they need, and layout.

Comment: Each of those bullet points should really be a separate question.

Comment: [Magazine template?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283119/11604)

Comment: [Persecution_of_New_Ideas](https://github.com/logological/blood) kind of shows how to do 3 columns interruptable with images, columns have a coloured line between them. Yet they seem to do manual [`\linebreak`ing all over](https://github.com/logological/blood/blob/master/Persecution_of_New_Ideas.tex#L351) and that kind of kills the idea of ease of use I would like...

Comment: [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/283037/108724) or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/451694/108724)

Comment: @C.F.G: really enjoyed your [first link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451694/is-there-a-latex-template-for-a-newspaper-style-letters-to-the-editor-page), thank you!)