# Illustrated encyclopedia template

Tags: templates

I want to make an illustrated encyclopedia similar to the one in these pictures, but have absolutely no clue how. Can someone provide me a template or information on it?[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  "How do I create this layout?" is not a good question for this site (nor most of the StackExchange).  I would encourage you to start learning the basics of laying things out in TeX.  3 columns with pictures isn't too hard.  Having text match a strange shape is fairly difficult.  Once you have a start but are stuck somewhere, you can create a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497) with your problem and we'd be glad to help you out.

Answer (score 2):

- The two pages on top seem doable with standard LaTeX methods. The two pages below: no. Carefully cutting where text runs around such pictures is a task for a more graphically orientated software. I'd say InDesign and such. So if you want to create a graphically advanced encyclopedia, LaTeX might not be the way to go.
- If you decide to start with LaTeX, you need to learn the basics. Never ever again ask a question without a MWE.
- There are multiple questions about a more graphical layout, see here e.g. [»Drowning witch in Oxford«](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/451694/4736).