# How can I make a manual a cover for a report?

Tags: titles

I need a simple cover but I don't know how set personalized spaces and positions to achieve what I really want. I need something like this

```
Education Institution
Location






                   Centered title a little over the middle page
                  hopefully with a letter more bigger than normal









                                            Author             : my
                                            Responsable Teacher: my teacher
                                            Course             : mycourse
                                            Date               : 7/7/2011
                                            Note the aligned   : Colons!
```

I hope someone could give me a hint.

Comment: @voodoomsr: I just noticed that you have accepted answers to a lot of your questions, but that you have cast only one vote so far. Please note that upvoting an answer has to be done separately from accepting it.

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17579/how-can-i-design-a-book-cover/17585#17585

Comment: @lockstep i don't get your point, can you rephrase?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides no their not the same. Look the solutions difference. What i ask is very simple wihout the use of any sophisticated package. The 2 answers that i get here is all that i need.

Comment: @voodoomsr I think lockstep's point is that although you've asked 11 questions (and accepted many of them) the fact that you have cast only one vote means that even for answers which you have accepted, you haven't given them votes.  Minimally it makes sense give a vote to any answer you accept; it's also reasonable to upvote similar answers that are also helpful, even if you don't accept them. (This is especially true in the case of multiple near identical answers to a question.)

Comment: @AlanMunn thanks for the clarification. What i think is that if i make a difficult and sophisticated question then the answers deserves to be upvoted. If i make a very simple one, the question and answer not necessarily need to be upvoted. If there was an extremely need to upvote any answer then an automatic code would do that for us, but it doesn't.

Comment: @voodoomsr If the question is so simple, then you could have found the answer by googling on your own; if not, then surely the answer deserves an upvote. Also, what counts as a "simple question" will vary greatly by user skill and experience. From my perspective, *many* questions are simple, but that doesn't mean that they are simple to the people who asked them. Voting also serves as a way for others to see that answers work, they also provide a bit of incentive for users to keep answering (everyone here *is* a volunteer, after all.)

Comment: @AlanMunn i agree with almost everything that you say except from the fact that i think that a typical users of Q&A StackExchange sites help others with out expecting any retribution. If i could help others i just do it. I don't think that the upvote mechanism is for express feelings like "thank you very much", "you save my day", "etc".  I see it as a mechanism to claim that definitely this could trascend beyond the closed meaning of the question and could help others even more from what it helped me. Still is a very subjective topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{flushleft}
Education Institution\\
Location
\end{flushleft}

\vspace*{3cm}
\begin{center}
\Large Centered title a little cover over the middle page
\end{center}

\vfill

\begin{flushright}
\begin{tabular}{l@{:\hspace*{\tabcolsep}}l}
Author & my \\
Respansable Teacher & my teacher \\
\end{tabular}
\end{flushright}

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is wise to separate content from presentation by placing the title, author, date, etc in macros defined at the very beginning of the document. Then, if your title page becomes complex you don't have to hunt around in the styling markup for what needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

```
\begin{titlepage}
\parindent=0pt
Education Institution\\
Location

\vfill
\begin{center}
Centered title a little over the middle page\\
hopefully with a letter more bigger than normal
\end{center}

\vfill
\hfill\begin{tabular}{l@{: }l}
Author             & my\\
Responsable Teacher& my teacher\\
Course             & mycourse\\
Date               & 7/7/2011\\
Note the aligned   & Colons!\\
\end{tabular}
\end{titlepage}
```