# Empty page inserted with pspicture environment

Tags: pstricks, book-design

From the question [How can I design a book cover](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17579/how-can-i-design-a-book-cover), I tried to compile the code from Dean Serenevy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\psset{unit=1in}
\begin{pspicture}(7,9.5)% use your page size
  \rput[b](3.5,8){\parbox{5in}{\begin{flushright}
    \Huge\bfseries\sffamily Awk one-liners\\ Explained
    \end{flushright}}}
  \uput[-90](3.5,8){\color{red}\rule{5in}{1ex}}
  % ...
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

This is the pdf file generated. The problem is that I have a blank page, and I can't remove the line number with `\thispagestyle{empty}`. What might be wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values you have set as the "page size", (which is meant to be the text block size) don't match the actual text block size. (They're too big, so you get an extra page.)  Here's the same example with the text block set explicitly with the `geometry` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[text={7in,9.5in},centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\psset{unit=1in}
\begin{pspicture}(7,9.5)% use your page size
  \rput[b](3.5,8){\parbox{5in}{\begin{flushright}
    \Huge\bfseries\sffamily Awk one-liners\\ Explained
    \end{flushright}}}
  \uput[-90](3.5,8){\color{red}\rule{5in}{1ex}}
  % ...
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @prosseek instead of `\pagestyle` you could try to put the code in the `{titlepage}`-environment. So it is typset on its own empty page.