# Custom title page in report or book class?

Tags: titles, book-design, report

I have a long academic report to write and I am thinking of using the book class or the report class? However in both these classes the title page has the title in the centre. I want to make my own title page with a few images related to the report, the logo of my instititute etc.? How to do this?

Comment: Take a look at »[titlepages](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlepages)« for some inspiration.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17579/how-can-i-design-a-book-cover. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: You may also want to have a look at Vincent Zoonekynd's title page designs: http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_title/0.html

Comment: Related [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209993)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is the extreme abuse of features provided by LaTex. This should serve as a model and the length parameters can be changed as per personal needs.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[tc]{titlepic}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[executivepaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\definecolor{title}{RGB}{180,0,0}
\definecolor{other}{RGB}{171,0,255}
\definecolor{name}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{phd}{RGB}{0,0,240}
\begin{document}
\title{\bfseries {\sc\textcolor{title}{The title of your report goes here and \\ this is the second line}}}
\author{\textcolor{other}{Thesis  submitted to} \\[5pt]
\emph{\textcolor{other}{Your University}}\\[2cm]
 \textcolor{other}{in partial fulfilment for the award of the degree
 of} \\[2cm]
\textsc{\Large{\textcolor{phd}{Doctor of Philosophy}}} \\[5pt]
  \textcolor{other}{in some subject} \vspace{0.4cm} \\[1in]
  \textcolor{other}{By}\\[5pt] {\Large \sc \textcolor{name}{Me}}
   \vspace{2cm}
\titlepic{\includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{example-image-a}\\[5pt]
\textcolor{other}{Department of Subject}\\[5pt]
 \textcolor{other}{Address line -- 2}\\[5pt]
 \textcolor{other}{Address line -- 4,
 INDIA}\\
 \vfill
 \textcolor{other}{April 2011}}}

\date{}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Option -- 2**

One can simply use `titlepage` as an alternative. Here we don't use `\title` and `\author` but everything is done manually.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[executivepaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
 {\huge\bfseries The title of your report goes here and \\ this is the second line\\}
 % ----------------------------------------------------------------
 \vspace{1.5cm}
 {\Large\bfseries Author -- 1}\\[5pt]
 email@gmail.com\\[14pt]
  % ----------------------------------------------------------------
 \vspace{2cm}
{Thesis  submitted to} \\[5pt]
\emph{{Your University}}\\[2cm]
{in partial fulfilment for the award of the degree
 of} \\[2cm]
\textsc{\Large{{Doctor of Philosophy}}} \\[5pt]
{in some subject} \vspace{0.4cm} \\[2cm]
% {By}\\[5pt] {\Large \sc {Me}}
 \vfill
 % ----------------------------------------------------------------
\includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{example-image-a}\\[5pt]
{Department of Subject}\\[5pt]
{Address line -- 2}\\[5pt]
{Address line -- 4,
 INDIA}\\
 \vfill
{April 2011}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Putting markup (like `\textsc`) in the the metadata declarations (like `\title`) is not a good idea. Anything other appearance of the title will have the same styling.

Answer (score 3):

The above answer summarizes it all. However, here is another simpler cover page, which one can easily comprehend-

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[top=1.2in, bottom=1.2in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\begin{spacing}{1.5}
Internship Project Report\\
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{spacing}
\begin{spacing}{2.5}
\textbf{\huge The Title of Image Comes Here}\\[0.5cm]
\vspace*{\fill}
\textit{Submitted by}
\end{spacing}

\begin{spacing}{1.15}
\textbf{\large Your Name}

\textbf{\large Other Details}

\vspace*{\fill}

\textnormal{\large Department \\ Institute Name\\ Location\\ Date}

\end{spacing}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and the second option of the accepted answer? As I see it, the last edit of the accepted answer dates back two years before this answer.