# How to add more information to the front page using document class report?

Tags: titles, report

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom title page in report or book class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59460/custom-title-page-in-report-or-book-class)

I am trying to write my PhD proposal using the document class `report`. I borrowed the simplest template from:
http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/thesis/examples/index.html

On the first page I wanted to a couple more sentences like "A proposal submitted to so and so university for so and so PhD." I pasted the code below. Is there a simple way to add a statement? Have I chosen a wrong template for my proposal?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\begin{document}

\title{A Sample PhD Thesis}
\author{A. N. Other}
\date{July 2004}

\maketitle

\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction}
\label{ch:intro}

\chapter{Technical Introduction}
\label{ch:techintro}

\chapter{Method}
\label{ch:method}

\chapter{Results}
\label{ch:results}

\chapter{Conclusions}
\label{ch:conc}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{thesis}

\end{document}
```

Comment: use the environment `titlepage` for an extended title and not the macro `\maketitle`

Comment: IMO, you should go with Herbert's recommendation but you could also try something like `\date{July 2004 \\\vfill <YOUR TEXT>}`.

Comment: Shashank: I have given a link above. I hope you can use the code given there as a template. Both the misuse of `\title` and `\author` and using `\titlepage` are discussed there. If you need any more help please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Sorry, indeed, it seems that this template does not allow it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\begin{document}

\title{A Sample PhD Thesis}
\author{A. N. Other}
\date{July 2004}

\maketitle
```

Just type after this make title, and it will still appear on that page. (for instance your line). If preferred, put it in a `\center{ }` environment.
There are also things like acknowledgements that have their own command (for instance, supervisor or something).

```
\pagebreak %this will stop that page prematurely
```