# how to customize a title page

Tags: titles, thesis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom title page in report or book class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59460/custom-title-page-in-report-or-book-class)

How do you customize the way a title page is generated (be it external package or some other redefinition of `\maketitle`)? My university is requiring a special format for my thesis title page, including specific spacing (title must be 2 inches from the top), and extra content (blurb about this being a thesis, lines for advisors to sign). The requirements document is [here](http://honors.fye.byu.edu/sites/default/files/student_files/ThesisFormattingGuidelines.pdf). I am using the `report` class.

Comment: Is http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59466/11232 useful?

Comment: Yup! Thanks for that. Provided those answers still work in `report`, this question is a duplicate.

Comment: They will work in report too. If you have difficulties pl. let us know. :-)