# How to change caption in a figure?

Tags: captions, titles

Let us consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\title{\textbf{ \Huge{My \LaTeX}}}
\author{\textbf{MKS}}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}[c]
 \begin{center}

\rotatebox{0}{\scalebox{.40}{\includegraphics{fig1.png}}}
\caption{This is a Flower}

\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This gives :

[image]
[image] 
That is they take two different pages. I want to do it in a single page as well as I want to change the caption given in the following figure :

[image]

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59460/custom-title-page-in-report-or-book-class

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

```
\begin{figure}[c]
```

figure does not have a `c` option so that is a syntax error, but this image appears to be
part of the title layout so not a float at all so you do not want the `figure` environment at all.

```
\begin{center}
```

OK although it introduces vertical space

```
\rotatebox{0}{\scalebox{.40}{\includegraphics{fig1.png}}}
```

`\rotatebox{0}` (as has been previously noted) is just an inefficient way of doing `\mbox` `\scalebox` can be more simply done by using the scale options on the graphic.

```
\caption{This is a Flower}

\end{center}
```

Just use

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{fig1.png}

This is a flower
\end{center}
```

In the case of `book` you need to add this to `\maketitle` (oruse the `titlepage` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\long\def\addimage#1\vfil#2\vfil#3!!{\def\maketitle{#1\vfil#2\titleimage\vfil#3}}
\expandafter\addimage\maketitle!!

\begin{document}
\title{\textbf{ \Huge{My \LaTeX}}}
\author{\textbf{MKS}}
\date{\today}

\newcommand\titleimage{%
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{fig1.png}
\par
This is a Flower
\end{center}}

\maketitle


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\maketitle` is placed on a separate page in `book`, is it not? The OP wanted title and image on the same page.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thanks didn't notice book, will update

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle. My one problem is solved. But the other yet not.For this cooperation +1 for you.

Comment: @MdKutubuddinSardar code updated for book

Answer (score 3):

use the environment `titlepage`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\textbf{\Huge My \LaTeX}

\vspace{1cm}
\textbf{MKS}

\vspace{1cm}
\today

\vspace{2cm}
\rotatebox{0}{\scalebox{.40}{\includegraphics{flower}}}
\captionof*{figure}{This is a Flower}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

foo

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try by using the `titlepage` environment.  As per [LaTeX Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation):

```
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

% Upper part of the page. The '~' is needed because \\
% only works if a paragraph has started.
\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{./logo}~\\[1cm]

\textsc{\LARGE University of Beer}\\[1.5cm]

\textsc{\Large Final year project}\\[0.5cm]

% Title
\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \huge \bfseries Lager brewing techniques}\\[0.4cm]

\HRule \\[1.5cm]

% Author and supervisor
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
John \textsc{Smith}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
Dr.~Mark \textsc{Brown}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}

\vfill

% Bottom of the page
{\large \today}

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

The result will be something like this:

[image]