# Create a book cover with spine, rear page and flaps

Tags: titles, templates, book-design, zwpagelayout

I have just finished my thesis, and I want to ask if there is a way to create a front-title page with spine (I don't know if this is the right term for the area between front page and rear page)? I would also like to include a back page.

Some preliminary ideas are shown bellow

[image]

I found a package called `zwpagelayout` which allows somehow to create a spine and flaps as well. I tried to use it by

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[papersize={,293mm}, topmargin=2mm, botmargin, strictheight, leftmargin=0mm, flap=50mm, textwidth=209mm, spine=13mm, cropmarks, cropframe, croptitle=Πρότυπο Εξωφύλλου]{zwpagelayout}
\linespread{1}

\begin{document}
 Εξώφυλλο
\end{document}
```

Using this code produces an error that `spine is not defined`...
Any ideas?

I edited the previous code and the result is

[image]

Now I have to find a way to "move" around pages...
Any ideas will over-welcomed!!!

I also used this

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\pagestyle{empty}

\makeatletter
 \def\La{%
  L\kern-.36em{%
  \setbox0\hbox{T}%
  \vbox to\ht0{%
    \hbox{$\m@th$%
      \csname S@\f@size\endcsname
      \fontsize\sf@size\z@
      \math@fontsfalse\selectfont A}%
      \vss%
    }%
  }%
}
\def\AllTeX{(\La\kern-.075em)\kern-.075em\TeX}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\psset{unit=1in,linewidth=2pt}%
\psline(-0.75,2)(-0.75,-\paperheight)%
\psline(-0.25,2)(-0.25,-\paperheight)%
\rput[lb]{90}(-0.3,-0.75\paperheight){\red\Huge\textbf{Study}}%
\rput[lb]{90}(-0.4,-0.1\paperheight){\red\Huge\textbf{MicroMEGAS}}%

\vspace*{3cm}
\centerline{\Huge \textbf{P}ost\textbf{S}cript \textbf{T}ricks}

\vspace{2cm}
\centerline{\Large Athanasios Stamatopoulos}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

but my compiler cannot recognise commands like the following

```
\psline(-0.75,2)(-0.75,-\paperheight)%
```

The output from this code is

[image]

As you see no spine is produced. Instead spine is inserted in frontpage...

I have found a way to move around pads...
The complete and correct code is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[papersize={,293mm}, topmargin=2mm, botmargin, strictheight, leftmargin=0mm, flap=50mm, textwidth=209mm, spine=13mm, cropmarks, cropframe, croptitle=Πρότυπο Εξωφύλλου]{zwpagelayout}
\linespread{1}

\begin{document}
 \hbox to \textwidth{%
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropFlap \centering
Back flap\vfill}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \UserWidth \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}\draw (0,0) --(5,5);\end{tikzpicture}\vfill \leavevmode     ISBN+EAN}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropSpine \centering
\vfill
\begin{sideways}Name Title\end{sideways}\vfill}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \UserWidth \centering
Front cover\vfill \LaTeX}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropFlap \centering
Front flap\vfill}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's kinda hard to propose you some "fancy" things without knowing anything about your thesis. Of course we could propose some generic things but those might look like the default designs provided by power point. In the end it is you who knows best, *what* could be on the title. We can only do the technical support or give advise how to optimize an already existing concept...

Comment: You might want to look at these [posts](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=fancy+cover+using+tikz)

Comment: I removed the generic title page part of your question because a) we only want one question per post here and b) you'll most likely find this question answer on tex.sx already, e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17579/how-can-i-design-a-book-cover, and, as @BenediktBauer remarked, the question was really open. The way it is now, this is an interesting and good question. Hope that edit is ok with you.

Comment: @BenediktBauer: Check my updated question!

Comment: @hpesoj626:I did, beforehand but I wan't able to find something interesting.

Comment: @doncherry: This is fine by me!

Comment: Related: [How can I design a book cover?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17579/how-can-i-design-a-book-cover). Then you can combine with `zwpagelayout` to arrive at your desired output.

Comment: I believe the `spine` option should take a value like, say `8mm`. Try `[spine=8mm]`.

Comment: @hpesoj626:I used `[spine=8mm]` but spine is not printed

Comment: I also tried another code...Please check my updated question.

Comment: @hpesoj626:I found a way to create a cover template, but I have to find a way to move around pads...

Comment: If I hadn't upvoted already, I'd give you +1 for having the balls to post a mockup picture in Comic Sans on this site `:D`

Comment: Thank you for your comment! To be quite frank I don't see why this is so courageous but I'll accept it!!!Thank you!!!

Comment: The code is ready! I found a way to move around pads...Now all that's left is to design a nice looking coverpage... Any suggestions will be more than welcomed!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have completed three covers. My code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}
\usepackage[papersize={,297mm}, strictheight=false,topmargin=0mm, botmargin, flap=50mm, textwidth=209mm, spine=13mm, cropmarks, cropframe, croptitle=Εξώφυλλο Διπλωματικής]{zwpagelayout}
\usepackage{rotating}
\linespread{1}
\begin{document}
    \hbox to \textwidth{%
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropFlap \centering \textcolor{white}{Front Flap}
}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \UserWidth \vfill \leavevmode \textcolor{white}{ISBN+EAN}}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropSpine \vfill
\begin{sideways}\hspace{-10cm}Αθανάσιος Ν. Σταματόπουλος \hspace{5cm}{\Large Μελέτη     Ανιχνευτή \latintext{MicroMEGAS}}  \end{sideways}\vfill}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \UserWidth \vspace{1cm} 
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\begin{picture}(20,27)

\put(0.7,1){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,1){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,2){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,2){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,3){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,3){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,4){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,4){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,5){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,5){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,6){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,6){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,7){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,7){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,8){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,8){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,9){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,9){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,10){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,10){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,11){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,11){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,12){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,12){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,13){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,13){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,14){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,14){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,15){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,15){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,16){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,16){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,17){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,17){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,18){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,18){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,19){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,19){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,20){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,20){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,21){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,21){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,22){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,22){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,23){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,23){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,24){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,24){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,25){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,25){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,26){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,26){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\put(3.4,23){\includegraphics[width=3.3cm]{ntua-logo}}
\put(7.1,25.4) {{\Large Εθνικό Μετσόβιο Πολυτεχνείο}}
\put(7.1,24.9) {{\Large Σχολή Εφαρμοσμένων Μαθηματικών\&Φυσικών Επιστημών}}
\put(7.1,24.4) {{\Large Τομέας Φυσικής}}
\put(7.1,23.9) {{\Large Εργαστήριο Πειραματικής Φυσικής Υψηλών Ενεργειών}}
\put(6,14){{\huge Μελέτη ανιχνευτή \latintext{MicroMEGAS}}}
\put(7.5,7.5){{\Large Σταματόπουλος Ν. Αθανάσιος}}
\put(9,1.5){{\Large Οκτώβριος 2012}}
\end{picture}}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropFlap \textcolor{white}{Back Flap}
}}

\newpage

\hbox to \textwidth{%
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropFlap \centering
\textcolor{white}{Back flap}\vfill}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \UserWidth \vfill \leavevmode \textcolor{white}{ISBN+EAN}}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropSpine \vfill
\begin{sideways}\hspace{-10cm}Αθανάσιος Ν. Σταματόπουλος \hspace{5cm}{\Large Μελέτη     Ανιχνευτή \latintext{MicroMEGAS}}  \end{sideways}\vfill}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \UserWidth \vspace{1cm} 
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\begin{picture}(20,27)


\put(0.7,1){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,1){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,2){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,2){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,3){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,3){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,4){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,4){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,5){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,5){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,6){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,6){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,7){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,7){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,8){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,8){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,9){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,9){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,10){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,10){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,11){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,11){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,12){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,12){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,13){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,13){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,14){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,14){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,15){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,15){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,16){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,16){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,17){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,17){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,18){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,18){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,19){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,19){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,20){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,20){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,21){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,21){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,22){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,22){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,23){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,23){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,24){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,24){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,25){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,25){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,26){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,26){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\put(9.5,23){\includegraphics[width=3.3cm]{ntua-logo}}
\put(8,22) {{\Large Εθνικό Μετσόβιο Πολυτεχνείο}}
\put(5,21.5) {{\Large Σχολή Εφαρμοσμένων Μαθηματικών\&Φυσικών Επιστημών}}
\put(9.5,21) {{\Large Τομέας Φυσικής}}
\put(5.5,20.5) {{\Large Εργαστήριο Πειραματικής Φυσικής Υψηλών Ενεργειών}}
\put(6,14){{\huge Μελέτη ανιχνευτή \latintext{MicroMEGAS}}}
\put(7.5,7.5){{\Large Σταματόπουλος Ν. Αθανάσιος}}
\put(9,1.5){{\Large Οκτώβριος 2012}}
\end{picture}}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropFlap \centering
\textcolor{white}{Front flap}\vfill}}

\newpage

\hbox to \textwidth{%
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropFlap 
\vspace{20.5cm} \begin{tikzpicture}\draw[color=gray!50,fill=gray!50] (0,0) rectangle     (5,-2);\end{tikzpicture}\vfill}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \UserWidth \vspace{20.5cm}     \begin{tikzpicture}\draw[color=gray!50,fill=gray!50] (-2,0) rectangle     (30,-2);\end{tikzpicture}}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropSpine \vfill
\begin{sideways}\hspace{-10cm}Αθανάσιος Ν. Σταματόπουλος  \hspace{5cm}{\Large Μελέτη     Ανιχνευτή \latintext{MicroMEGAS}}  \end{sideways}\vfill}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \UserWidth \vspace{1cm} \line(1,0){40}{} \Large Σταματόπουλος     Ν. Αθανάσιος \line(1,0){320}\\ \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}\begin{picture}(27,17)
\put(1,7){\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{ntua-logo}}
\put (5.5,9.5){\Large Εθνικό Μετσόβιο Πολυτεχνείο}
\put (5.5,9){\Large Σχολή Εφαρμοσμένων Μαθηματικών\&Φυσικών Επιστημών}
\put (5.5,8.5) {\Large Τομέας Φυσικής}
\put (5.5,8) {\Large Εργαστήριο Πειραματικής Φυσικής Υψηλών Ενεργειών}
\put (1,1) {\huge Μελέτη ανιχνευτή \latintext{MicroMEGAS}}\end{picture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[color=white,opacity=1] (0,2) -- (10,2);
\draw[color=gray!50,fill=gray!50] (0,0) rectangle (25,-2);
\node at (3,-6) {\large Οκτώβριος 2012};
\end{tikzpicture}
}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropFlap \vspace{20.5cm}     \begin{tikzpicture}\draw[color=gray!50,fill=gray!50] (0,0) rectangle     (4.5,-2);\end{tikzpicture}\vfill}}

\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]
[image]
[image]
What do you guys think?Which is better for a thesis? Any other suggestions are welcomed!!!

---

**Edit:**I also added an alternative to the last cover in a color version.

The code is

```
 \hbox to \textwidth{%
 \vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropFlap 
 \vspace{20.5cm} \begin{tikzpicture}\draw[color=red,fill=red] (0,0) rectangle     (5,-2);\end{tikzpicture}\vfill}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \UserWidth \vspace{20.5cm}     \begin{tikzpicture}\draw[color=red,fill=red] (-2,0) rectangle     (30,-2);\end{tikzpicture}}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropSpine \vfill
\begin{sideways}\hspace{-10cm}\textcolor{blue}{Αθανάσιος Ν. Σταματόπουλος}  \hspace{5cm}    {\Large \textcolor{blue}{Μελέτη Ανιχνευτή \latintext{MicroMEGAS}}}      \end{sideways}\vfill}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \UserWidth \vspace{1cm} \begin{tikzpicture}\draw[red,very     thick] (0,0) --(3,0); \node at (6.3,0) {\Large Σταματόπουλος Ν. Αθανάσιος}; \draw[red,very     thick] (9.6,0) -- (20,0); \end{tikzpicture}\\ \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}\begin{picture}    (27,17)
\put(1,7){\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{ntua-logo}}
\put (5.5,9.5){\Large Εθνικό Μετσόβιο Πολυτεχνείο}
\put (5.5,9){\Large Σχολή Εφαρμοσμένων Μαθηματικών\&Φυσικών Επιστημών}
\put (5.5,8.5) {\Large Τομέας Φυσικής}
\put (5.5,8) {\Large Εργαστήριο Πειραματικής Φυσικής Υψηλών Ενεργειών}
\put (1,1) {\huge Μελέτη ανιχνευτή \latintext{MicroMEGAS}}\end{picture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[color=white,opacity=1] (0,2) -- (10,2);
\draw[color=red,fill=red] (0,0.2) rectangle (25,-1.8);
\node at (3,-6) {\large Οκτώβριος 2012};
\end{tikzpicture}
}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropFlap \vspace{20.5cm}     \begin{tikzpicture}\draw[color=red,fill=red] (0,0) rectangle     (4.5,-2);\end{tikzpicture}\vfill}}
```

The output of this code is as follows

[image]

What would you guys choose?

Comment: This is nice.  Suggest you consider submitting this template to http://www.latextemplates.com/

Comment: Really?Thank you very much! I have just done it! I hope people will find it useful! Any comments or opinions on which is best suitable for a thesis?

Comment: It gives fatal error when I run on pdfLaTeX today!

Answer (score 4):

Just came across the [bookcover package](https://ctan.org/pkg/bookcover)—from 2015, still updated in 2020—where you can do:

### Dust cover

[image: dust cover]

### Two-sided book cover

[image: two-sided book cover]
[image: two-sided book cover]

Comment: The Two Sided Book Cover image is flashing unpleasantly, at least when viewed on an android phone.

Comment: @Anush - Fixed using poppler, it's now two separate images

Comment: I think the `bookcover` class is the most convenient and fastest possible solution for this task. I’ve already made a lot of covers with this.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create the front and back cover artwork in a graphics program. This is the advice contained in the Koma-script manual if I remember correctly. Once you have the front and back cover, you can use the LaTeX bookcover package to properly generate a the cover.

I believe it's possible to use the bookcover package to impose graphics on the page as you wish, but I haven't used it for that purpose.