# Cover/Wrapper for thesis

Tags: printing, covers

I am soon finishing my thesis and need some advice on how to create the cover/wrapper that surrounds the thesis (cover page + spine + back). Since it will be printed I also need to add some X's in the corners, so the printing comany will know where to cut the pages and finally I need 3mm of extra page color all the way around the page. I have tried to illustrate what I need to create here:

[image]

As you can see, I need 1 page that includes all (front, spine, back, crosses) and it should have a size of Width: 43.6cm height: 30.3cm.

Can you adwise me on how to proceed with this task? I also Wonder if there are some other tools for this, however, my thesis is written in with latex.

**UPDATE**
I have tried to follow the other examples gives, but I cannot get it to Work. I hope some of you can see the problem :)

Here is a working sample: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/54872816859f4c414814c129

Comment: @percusse Thanks. Actually the referenced question did not answer my question. However, there were links to another question (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78277/create-a-book-cover-with-spine-rear-page-and-flaps/81630#81630), which might just Work. I will at least try it. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. They do the same thing with different syntax. \

Comment: @percusse Hello Again, I have tried now, but I cannot get it to Work. I have a working example here: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/54872816859f4c414814c129 so hope you can help me. Just look at the bottom of main.