# How to Add Spine to Cover Page of Thesis

Tags: bookcover

I was wondering if anyone could please tell me how could I generate a spine like this on the cover page of my thesis?

[image]

Comment: Check out this thread: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78277/create-a-book-cover-with-spine-rear-page-and-flaps

Comment: Note that the cover uses a different paper size, which is easier to do as a separate document.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/change-paper-size-in-mid-document?s=3|81.7794

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% THESE ARE LaTeX DEFAULTS; CAN CHANGE IF NEEDED.
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddThispageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{#3}}}}
% VERIFIED THAT SETTING \hoffset AND \voffset DO NOT BREAK SOLUTION.
%\hoffset=0.4in
%\voffset=0.2in
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\atxy{1in}{1in}{\rotatebox[origin=l]{-90}{\fbox{\makebox[9in]{\sffamily%
UMUT SAGLIKLU\hfill ANSWERING THAT PROVERBIAL QUESTION\hfill
Bilkent University 2016\rule[-10pt]{0pt}{25pt}}}}}
\sffamily
\begin{center}
ANSWERING THAT PROVERBIAL QUESTION\\
HOW MUCH LONGER WILL YOU BE IN SCHOOL?%
\vspace{1in}

A Master's Thesis
\vspace{1in}

by\
UMUT SAGLIKLI
\vspace{3in}

Department of\\
Ihsan Dogramaci Bilkent University\\
Ankara\\
September 2016
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

REF: [What are the ways to position things absolutely on the page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page/169831#169831)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (not so) MWE.
The spinewidth is given by the formula `((grammage / 1000) * main) * (num_pages /2) + (plat * 2)`

```
% !TeX TS-encoding = utf8
% !TeX TS-spellcheck = fr_FR
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[markcolor=black,coverwidth=210mm,coverheight=297mm,spinewidth=64.53082pt, bleedwidth=2.5mm]{bookcover}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}%,Numbers=OldStyle}% ,Scale=MatchLowercase} bug in current Biolinum
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{impnattypo}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning,}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\pgfextractlength{mO{1}mO{center}mO{center}}{%
\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{#3}{#4}}
{\pgfpointanchor{#5}{#6}}
\pgf@xa=\pgf@x % no need to use a new dimen
\pgf@ya=\pgf@y
\pgfmathparse{#2*veclen(\pgf@xa,\pgf@ya)/28.45274} % to convert from pt to cm   
\global\let#1\pgfmathresult % we need a global macro
}
\makeatother

\def\annee{}
\newcommand{\Annee}[1]{\def\annee{#1}}

\definecolor{bleu045}{rgb}{0, .17, .45}
\definecolor{estia}{RGB}{0,158,225}

\Annee{2017}
\def\gram{80}
\def\main{1.8}
\def\plat{0}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\longueur}{\coverwidth+\bleedwidth}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Ltitre}{.6*\coverwidth}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Htitre}{.4*\spinewidth}
\begin{bookcover}
\bookcovercomponent{center}{above front}{
\color{red}Paramètres: largeur=\the\coverwidth, hauteur=\the\coverheight, fond perdu=\the\bleedwidth, dos=\the\spinewidth, grammage=\gram, main=\main, plat carton=\plat pt}

\bookcovercomponent{tikz}{spine}{
    \node at (part.center) [rotate=90, anchor=center] {\resizebox{\Ltitre pt}{!}{\bfseries\scshape Publications scientifiques — \annee}};
%   \node at (part.center) [rotate=90, anchor=center] {\resizebox{!}{\Htitre pt}{\bfseries\scshape Publications scientifiques — \annee}};
    \node at ($(part.south)+(0,\bleedwidth)$) [rotate=90, anchor=west] {Logo};
}

\bookcovercomponent{tikz}{bg front}{
    \node (batiment) at (part.north) [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=north] {image};
    \node (lisere) [below=0pt of batiment, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, minimum width=\longueur pt, minimum height=1cm, fill=estia, fill opacity=.4]{};
    \coordinate (ctitre) at (part.center);
    \pgfextractlength{\lAB}{lisere}[south]{ctitre}
    \node (titre) at (ctitre) [minimum width=\longueur pt, minimum height=\lAB * 2cm, align=center, font={\bfseries}, preaction={fill=bleu045, fill opacity=.4}]{\scalebox{2}{Publications scientifiques}\\[1em] \scalebox{2}{\annee}\\[1.5em]{\Large Rapport interne}};
    \pgfextractlength{\lBC}[.25]{titre}[south]{current page}[south]
    \node at($(titre.south)!.5!(part.south)$) {\includegraphics[height=\lBC cm]{Logo}};
}
\end{bookcover}
\end{document}
```