# Are there any packages providing collections of title pages?

Tags: packages, titles

I'm looking for a way to easily experiment with different title page styles, without having to design them myself. Something similar to what ms word offers.

Comment: The `memoir` class provides a bunch of different predefined page styles. [Title Pages](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlepages). You can find many, *many* more examples online, but please be careful. Not all show good or even correct LaTeX. The above linked examples should be fine, though.

Comment: Good to know. A package would still be preferred to a class, as one might be bound to a different class for some reason.

Comment: Those are just examples, you would need to copy the code and make some mminor adjustments. A general package is quite difficult to do. With the standard title, you have `author`, `title`  and `date`, but you much likely want to include a publisher, a location, some copyright note or in case of a thesis the university name and logo, the degree that's gonna be achieved, the names of the supervisors. There are really too many variables to pre-pack stuff.

Comment: You can load the `titling` package, also written by Pater Wilson, for an easy customisation off title pages.

Comment: `titlepages` is not a class. It is a series of examples and not dependent on any particular class. Although obviously some examples would not work with some classes without modification. Do note that 'what MS Word offers' may seem to be a matter of common knowledge, but is rather less likely to be so among the denizens of this site. I have no idea what it offers and I'm sure I'm not the only one.

Comment: Surely the better approach is to decide on the design (either on your own or by finding a style you like by searching online or looking at some of the nicer books on your shelves), then make it.  If you get stuck, then you can ask one or more concrete questions here.  I've no idea what MS Word offers either, but you can surely do better than that....

Comment: You can also have a look at [github - titlepageExamples](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/titlepages)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Topic titlepage](https://www.ctan.org/topic/titlepage) on CTAN:

- [titlepages](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlepages) – Sample titlepages, and how to code them. (The package consist only in a PDF and the TeX source).

May be also useful:

- [ti­tle­foot](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlefoot) - Add spe­cial ma­te­rial to footer of ti­tle page
- [ti­tlepic](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlepic)  - Add pic­ture to ti­tle page of a doc­u­ment.
- [ti­tling](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titling) - Con­trol over the type­set­ting of the `\maketi­tle` com­mand.

May be too specific but source code could help for your own title page:

- [ti­tlepage-uni-dort­mund](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlepage-uni-dortmund) - Titlepage for Univer­sity of Dort­mund (Ger­many)

Besides, may be you want also  a cover ...

- [bookcover](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bookcover) – A class for book covers and dust jackets

And these are not CTAN  packages but ...

- [LaTeX Templates Title Pages](http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/title-pages)
- [Title page with logo](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/title-page-with-logo/hrskypjpkrpd#.Vn6DkHUR9Bc)
- And of course, some Q & A from this site, specially [Showcase of beautiful title page done in TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85904) and [How can I design a book cover?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17579/how-can-i-design-a-book-cover)

Comment: All titlepages from l-templates are taken from Wikibook or Frits' website and all are more or less buggy and not recommendable.

Comment: [Showcase of beautiful title page done in TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85904)

Comment: @Johannes_B just now I was searching for this link. Thanks