# Need help with structuring text with figures?

Tags: titles

[image: A template for thesis]

I need help in order to be able to make this for my own thesis. If anyone would try to help me, I would be very thankful.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! While not exactly the same, perhaps some inspiration for techniques can be found in the answers to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17579/how-can-i-design-a-book-cover/17580#17580 Another way would be to create a PDF in whichever other software you like that is capable of doing such things, and include it in your document with e.g. the `pdfpages` package. Edit: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85904/showcase-of-beautiful-title-page-done-in-tex/86079#86079 has some more such examples.

Comment: If you can get the seal as an image file and edit it to make the background transparent, everything else can be done with LaTeX.  (Maybe TikZ for the ribbon.)

Answer (score 2):

Components:

- Logo: I found a logo with higher resolution at a [university page](https://www.natur.cuni.cz/geografie/demografie-a-geodemografie/ke-stazeni/loga-1/logo-univerzity-karlovy-v-praze/view).
  As member of the university you can maybe get a good vector
  graphics version of the logo. Also the next steps might not be necessary
  with the a vector graphics version.

  The image on the website was then loaded in an image manipulating program, gimp:

  - The white margins are removed/the image cropped.
  - The white color is made transparent. In gimp I have used the menu entry "Colors → Colors to Alpha".
  - Then the image is exported as PNG file with transparency as
    file `logo_UK.png`.
- Colors.

  - The color of the red band can be derived from a color picker of an image program. I have taken the color from the name of the background image for the red menu bar at the [home page](https://www.natur.cuni.cz/geografie/demografie-a-geodemografie/ke-stazeni/loga-1/logo-univerzity-karlovy-v-praze/view) of the university. The result was the HTML color `#CC2C32`.
  - I have guessed the color for the gray background of the logo
    as 10 % black and 90 % white. The example draws the background
    via TikZ. Alternatively the background could be set in the
    image file.
- Measurements. The example below only uses rough guesses.
  The margins can be adopted using options of package `geometry`.
- The font seems to be Palatino, thus I have used package `tgpagella`,
  the clone for Palatino from the TeX Gyre project. The sizes are just
  simple guesses. Change them to your needs.

The following example generates one page with the title page.
This page can then be included with package `pdfpages` in the main
document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
  % your settings for the title page
]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\maxdepth}{0pt}

\newsavebox{\imagebox}
\sbox{\imagebox}{%
  \includegraphics[
    width=52mm,
  ]{logo_UK.png}%
}

\newdimen\RedBandWidth
\setlength{\RedBandWidth}{14mm}

\definecolor{RedBandColor}{HTML}{CC2C32}
\definecolor{LogoBackgroundColor}{gray}{.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt]
  \draw[
    RedBandColor,
    line width=\RedBandWidth,
    line cap=butt,
    <-,
    >={Triangle Cap[cap angle=105, reversed]},
  ]
    (0, 0) -- (0, \textheight)
  ;
  \fill[LogoBackgroundColor]
    (0, \textheight - \RedBandWidth - .5\ht\imagebox)
    circle[radius=.5\wd\imagebox - 1pt]
    node (image) {\usebox{\imagebox}}
  ;

  \coordinate (BotText) at (0, 21mm);

  \path[
    node font=\Large\bfseries\scshape,
    every node/.style={rotate=90},
  ]
    (BotText) node[white, right]
    {\strut\textls[70]{Matematicko-Fyzik\'aln\'ifakulta}}
    ++(-.5\RedBandWidth - 4mm, 0)
    node[above right]
    {\textls[70]{Univerzita Karlova v Praze}}
  ;

  \def\TextSep{5.5mm}
  \path
    (BotText) ++(.5\RedBandWidth + \TextSep, 0) coordinate (RightColumn)
    node[above right, align=left, font=\small] {%
      Katedra algebry\\
      Vedouc\'i pr\'ace: doc.\@ Mgr.\@ \v St\v ep\'an Holub, Ph.\@\,D.\\
      Studijn\'i program: Matematika\\
      Studijn\'i obor: obecn\'a matematika\\
      Praha 2013\vphantom{g}
    }
    (RightColumn) ++(0, 61mm)
    node[above right, font=\large\bfseries] (author) {Miroslav Ol\v s\'ak}
    (author.north west) ++(0, 12mm)
    node[above right, font=\LARGE\bfseries, align=left]
    {Kvadratick\'e rovnice\\na slovech}
    (image.east) ++(\TextSep, 0)
    node[right, font=\large\bfseries] {Bakal\'a\v rsk\'a pr\'ace}
  ;

  % Set bounding box to cover full text area
  \pgfresetboundingbox
  \useasboundingbox
    (0, 0) (image.west) ++(\textwidth, 0) (0, \textheight)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]