# Where can I see book cover examples using bookcover.cls?

Tags: bookcover

I've found that https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bookcover has the flexibility I was looking for. Sadly I lack of design skills. Where can I find good-taste examples of use of this package?

Comment: Did you notice that the package comes with two examples? If you do not have them, then download the complete package from CTAN. They look good to me. But no package can help if you do not have design skills. A few years ago, I created a book cover (softcover novel) using LaTeX for the cover text. Nothing to do with math. I did not use that package, but did it the hard way. But that was only the text. The underlying graphic image was created separately in a graphics program. Then I imported the LaTeX PDF as a graphics layer, at the necessary dpi resolution. Large file!

Comment: Yes, but they are not very nice.

Comment: I just one some simple example that looks nice where I can change the title, the color and the main image :D

Comment: The first thing to do before designing a cover is to read the book.  A cover that’s in good taste for one book may be in the worst taste for another.  So I’m not sure how we can address your question without knowing anything at all about your book.

Comment: @JuanjoConti Agreed that the package examples are not very "nice," but they are appropriate for the job, which is an academic work about mathematics. If you look at book covers for some very famous books, especially from the 1940s and 1950s in the U.S.A., you will see that the cover designs are very minimal. It was the fashion. I have seen recent books by authors whose books automatically sell to a certain reader base, just because of the genre and author's name. Again, minimal design. On the other hand, many poorly-written books in the fantasy genre have spectacularly good artwork.

Comment: @Thérèse The book is a CF one. It's about time travel and bachelor party.

Comment: See [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17579/how-can-i-design-a-book-cover) and related questions.