# Making a simple book cover using a open source Linux program?

Tags: bookcover

Wrote about 15 technical textbooks made in Latex. After that it goes to a printing company to make a real book out of it. The cover is very simple just a picture and some text but it needs a 'trim box and art box' etc. according to the printing company. I have a program that calculates the width of the back of the cover. My book covers are besides the pictures all the same, so I just need a template. To keep the price of the books as low as possible I like to make my own book cover. Are there any free programs that just make book covers? I found Scribus under Ubuntu but it looks quite complicated. If you can help me I will really appreciate it.
Regards,
Ep Gernaat Holland

Comment: Perhaps Inkscape?

Comment: check some of the examples here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17579/how-can-i-design-a-book-cover
also see the documentation  for `bookcover` https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bookcover?lang=de

Comment: Don't discount Scribus. It's an excellent piece of software and has everything you need to create files your printer will accept. You can do this kind of thing in LaTeX, but setting pdf boxes is a bit of a pain.