# Cover thesis Tufte style

Tags: thesis, tufte

I'm creating a thesis using the Tufte style template.
Obviously I have to change the cover that I would like to look like this:

[image]

How can I do?

## EDIT

I tried this code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{addmargin}[3cm]{0cm}

        \begin{flushright}

            Università degli Studi di Torino \\ Scuola di Scienze della Natura \\ Corso di Laurea Magistrale in Informatica

            \hfill\includegraphics[width=4cm]{Unito-logo.png}\par

            \vspace{3\baselineskip}

            {\Huge Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \\ consectetur adipiscing elit\par}

            \vspace{6\baselineskip}

            \textit{laureando}: \Large{Name Lastname}\\
            \textit{relatore}: \Large{Name Lastname}\\
            \textit{correlatrice}: \Large{Name Lastname}

            \vspace*{\fill}

            \par{2017--2018}

        \end{flushright}

    \end{addmargin}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

I'm quite satisfied but there are two problems:

1. the text `laureanda` is smaller than the others
2. I would like the block of text (`Università degli Studi di Torino \\ Scuola di Scienze della Natura \\ Corso di Laurea Magistrale in Informatica`) to be placed near the logo
3. The text `2017--2018` placed at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17579/15925 help?

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks but not much. Unfortunately I know very little about Latex because it is the first time I use it. The only alternative I have is to use a Word/Latex converter online but it doesn't seem to me the best solution...

Comment: Package `frontespizio` seems to be a good start, though i have to say: Without the basic knowledge that gets you a title page (reading an introduction), LaTeX won't be of much help to you. You will get frustrated.

Comment: btw: There is also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280 and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks, I changed the main message. Can you help me?

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks, I changed the main message. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Including visual help to see the page margins better:

[image: marielleTitlepage]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{showframe}% page margins show better
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{addmargin}[3cm]{0cm}
\raggedleft

\begin{tabular}[c]{r}
Università degli Studi di Torino \\ 
Scuola di Scienze della Natura \\ \\
Corso di Laurea Magistrale in Informatica
\end{tabular}\adjustimage{width=4cm,valign=c}{example-image-1x1}

\vspace{3\baselineskip}

{\Huge Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \\ consectetur adipiscing elit\par}

\vspace{6\baselineskip}
\Large
\textit{laureando}: Name Lastname\\
\textit{relatore}: Name Lastname\\
\textit{correlatrice}: Name Lastname

\vspace*{\fill}

2017--2018
\end{addmargin}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```