# Best way for creating a simple book cover for scrbook using an image and shaded text box

Tags: books, book-design, scrbook, bookcover

I am writing an scrbook and would like to create a cover consisting of only an image and a shaded text box like the one below.

[image]

Does anyone has a recipe for adding a similar cover to this template:

```
\documentclass[
a4paper, 
10pt,
pagesize,
titlepage=true,
numbers=noenddot,]{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{gg}
\chapter{cc}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Usually a book cover has three parts, front side, back of the book and rear side. For example can you use class `coverbook`. See for example question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17579/16550

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! I don't know if there is a template but you can easily cook up something of that sort.

```
\documentclass[
a4paper, 
10pt,
pagesize,
titlepage=true,
numbers=noenddot,]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[rotate=-90] at (current page.center)
{\includegraphics[width=\paperheight,height=\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}};
\node[fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,text opacity=1,font=\bfseries\sffamily,align=left,inner sep=5mm,anchor=north] at 
([yshift=-1cm]current page.north) 
{{\Huge How to hibernate}\\ {\Large A marmot's guide to hibernation}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\chapter{gg}
\chapter{cc}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain me how is it that a marmot can write a book about hibernation when it/s/he is asleep all of that time?

Comment: @gusbrs This will all be explained in the book. ;-)

Comment: :) I can imagine that the last folk that attempted to read it had slept by page 4! (This means the book is a great success of course).

Comment: Please add `text opacity=1` because otherwise the text will be quite "hidden".

Comment: Beautifully elegant and simple!!!! Thanks @marmot

Comment: @TeXnician Done, thanks a lot! (I was thinking that if I specifically say `fill opacity=0.5` then the other opacities would stay 1, but apparently not, the text was grayish/transparent.)