# Can someone help with pstricks formatting for my title page?

Tags: formatting, pstricks

I am trying to recreate [Dean Serenevy's pstricks title page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17579/how-can-i-design-a-book-cover/17589#17589). Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{scrarticle}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\pagestyle{empty}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{titlepage}
\psset{unit=1in}
    \begin{pspicture}(8.5,11)
        \rput[b](3.5,8){\parbox{5in}{\begin{flushright}
                    \Huge\bfseries\sffamily Title Line 1\\ Title Line 2
        \end{flushright}}}
        \uput[-90](3.5,8){\color{red}\rule{5in}{1ex}}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{titlepage}
\clearpage
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\section*{Introduction}
...
\end{document}
```

This is what I'm seeing in TeXstudio. Any advice??
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... What engine you are using? i.e., `LaTeX ->dvips -> PS2PDF` or `PDFLaTeX, etc.`?

Comment: using TeXStudio

Comment: TeXstudio is the editor not the engine. That is something like pdflatex, lualatex, ... You run the example with `pdflatex`, which is not directly possible. Use `xelatex` or package `auto-pst-pdf` or use text commands. See my answer

Answer (score 2):

Can be done with simple text commands:

```
\documentclass{scrarticle}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{titlepage}
\raggedleft
\Huge\bfseries\sffamily 
Title Line 1\\
Title Line 2

\textcolor{red}{\rule{\linewidth}{1ex}}
\end{titlepage}


\section*{Introduction}
...
\end{document}
```

[image]