# How can include a stylish Cover page in book class ? which should not effects the water mark of the document

Tags: covers, bookcover

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,etoolbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[head=43.61858pt, top=1.5in, bottom=1.5in, left=1in, right=1in,  
            footskip=1.5cm, % footskip margin
           ]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[c]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[l]{Left footer}
\fancyfoot[r]{Right footer}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\normalfont\Large\filleft\bfseries} % format applied to label+text
{}                                   % label
{1pc}                                % horizontal separation between label and title body
{%
{\huge\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}}   % <-- new
    % draw a box around the chapter number:
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
            enhanced,flushright upper,
            boxrule=0pt,
            colback=white,colframe=white!50!white,
            drop fuzzy midday shadow=white!50!white,
        width=3.5cm]
        \resizebox{3.0cm}{!}{\color{gray!80}\thechapter}%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
    %\Huge % <-- has no effect
    } % before the title body
[] 


\let\latexthesection\thesection

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{nameref}

\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.8em}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}


\titlespacing\section{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}


\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Tema}

\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx,eso-pic}
\usepackage{transparent}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
  \AtPageCenter{% At center of page
    \scalebox{10}{% Size (scaled 10x)
      \rotatebox{45}{% Angle
        \makebox[-5pt]{% Centered horizontally
          \color{red!50}% Colour
          {\transparent{0.1}\includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight,width=0.1\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{watermark.png}}
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},
bookmarksopen=true,
bookmarksopenlevel=0,
hypertexnames=false,
colorlinks=true,% Set to false to disable coloring links
citecolor=magenta,% The color of citations
linkcolor=black,% The color of references to document elements (sections, figures, etc)
urlcolor=mdtRed,% The color of hyperlinks (URLs)
pdfstartview={FitV},
unicode,
breaklinks=true,
}
\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{TEMA}
\chapter{NÚMEROS NATURALES. SISTEMAS DE NUMERACIÓN}
\begin{tabular}{l}

\ref{C1_S1} $\quad$ \nameref{C1_S1} \\ [2mm]


\end{tabular}

\vspace*{8mm}

La construcción de los números naturales se lleva a cabo a partir de la definición axiomática de Peano. Todos los conjuntos que cumplen dicha axiomática son isomorfos para el orden y a cualquiera de ellos se le llamará conjunto $\mathbb{N}$ de los números naturales. Como hay opiniones para todos los gustos, la nuestra es que reporta más ventajas que inconvenientes no considerar como número natural al cero, así es que para nosotros el primer número natural será el 1. Se definen a continuación, recurriendo al Principio de inducción, la suma y el producto de números naturales de manera que sean compatibles con el orden total de $\mathbb{N}$ y, como herramienta necesaria para los sistemas de numeración, se aborda la división de números naturales. Tras una breve y precipitada, pero necesaria, introducción del cero, se dan algunas consideraciones sobre los sistemas de numeración posicionales, se demuestra el Teorema fundamental de numeración, que permite escribir todo número natural en cualquier base $n > 1$ y se termina enumerando algunas de las propiedades básicas de la numeración. 
%-----------------------------------
%   SECTION 1
%-----------------------------------
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\section{Los números naturales} \label{C1_S1}
La mente humana asume sin esfuerzo la idea del conjunto de los números naturales como una cadena ordenada 1, 2, 3, 4, con un primer elemento (1) y en la que a cada número le sigue otro. Si se pretende, en cambio, dar una definición consistente del conjunto de los números naturales, debe acudirse, bien a la Teoría de Conjuntos, refiriendo los números naturales a otros conceptos previos, bien a los axiomas de Peano, caracterizando a estos números mediante determinadas propiedades.
\end{document}
```

I want to make cover page as shown in the image

[image: cover page]

Comment: The easiest way to do a cover page is to use TikZ and probably \titlepage.  For printing, cover pages are larger than the page size and have the edges cut off.  See section 5.3 of the geometry package.

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17579

Comment: To delay the watermark, just move the `\AddToShipoutPictureFG{…}` in the document body to the source of the first page, that should have it.

Comment: Can you help me to make a cover page like in the image on which the title will change chapter by chapter?. Because I want to add this cover page not only on the front of book. I also want to add this for every chapter and that's why the title on the cover page will change chapter by chapter.