# What is the best way to use Latex for literary documents?

Tags: book-design

I was wondering, just out of curiosity: what would be the best way to produce literature-related documents in Latex?

I have only ever written technical and scientific documents myself, so I really don't know if there are some famous packages that can help while writing literary documents.

I only know about the [Memoir class](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/) which can be useful to typeset books, but are there other suggested packages?

Comment: I'm afraid the question is too general. What kind of literature? (books of poetry, science fiction novels, drama scripts, etc.)

Comment: @Fran actually I didn't have something specific in mind, I'm interested in all kind of literature. I could change this into a community wiki, it could be interesting to have one answer for every type of document

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A think that the first step is take a look to the related  packages in [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/search).

After very little search, you can find, for example (is not an exhaustive list):

**Poetry related packages:**

- `alt­verse`  – Type­set­ting verse
- `gm­verse` – A pack­age for  type­set­ting (short) po­ems
- `po­et­ry­tex`  – Type­set an­tholo­gie of po­etry
- `verse`  – Aids for type­set­ting sim­ple verse

**Screenplay related  packages:**

- `drama` –  Pro­duc­tion-style stage script in LaTeX
- `drama­tist` –  Type­set dra­mas, both in verse and in prose
- `plari` – Type­set­ting stage­play scripts
- `play` - Type­set drama us­ing LaTeX
- `sc­mac` - Type­set scripts with Plain TeX
- `screen­play` – A class file to type­set screen­plays
- `ScriptTeX` – Macros for scripts and screen­plays
- `sides` – A LaTeX class for type­set­ting stage plays
- `stage` – A LaTeX class for stage plays
- `dialogue` (Frankenstein bundle) – Environment for citing short passages of scripted  dialogue.

**Typeset manuscripts packages**

- `book` and related `scrbook`, etc. (stating the obvious ... but why not?)
- `sffms` – Type­set­ting sci­ence fic­tion/fan­tasy manuscripts
- `mem­oir` – Class is for type­set­ting po­etry, fic­tion, non-fic­tion, and math­e­mat­i­cal works.
- `game­book` – Type­set game­books and other in­ter­ac­tive nov­els

Also many packages of book-hand or uncial fonts could be on-topic here.

Comment: You may also add a great book class: `tufte-book` which has major concerns on presenting information in a clear style. It also can be used as diary-book template, where there is room for many annotations.

Comment: @math Yes, [I know that](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99695/11604).