# Writing a Play in LaTeX

Tags: typography

How would you properly format a play? All I can think of is having a two-column document, bit I have no idea how to format lines or scenes correctly. I can try to find a picture of what I am looking for.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94262/5872).

Comment: Have you checked the `play` class? http://www.ctan.org/pkg/play