# Example gallery of classes, macros, packages, etc.?

Tags: packages, document-classes

Is there an example  gallery similar to http://texample.net/tikz/examples/ for mostly non-graphical classes, macros, CTAN contributions, etc.?

E.g., a gallery of examples for the packages available at the [CV Topic](http://www.ctan.org/topic/cv) would be handy to select or rule out a package for use.

Comment: You can find some templates in [How to Tex](http://www.howtotex.com/templates/) and [LaTeX Templates](http://www.latextemplates.com/).

Comment: They don’t have pictures, but these two questions go roughly in the direction you’re looking for, I think: [What packages do people load by default in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/553) and [What are the available "documentclass" types and their uses?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/782)

Answer (score 2):

In 2009 I made an overview on "standard" classes (article and book-like, no fancy stuff like CS). 
You find it at  http://tex.lickert.net/dokumente/classoverview/index_en.html

It seems the english full-version has a bug, but the short versions and the German version are still visible.

If you think, it is from interest I may look for an update.

---

A collection of bibstyles:
http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/reference/faq/bibstyles.pdf
(From [LaTeX FAQ at C.U.](http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/reference/faq/#bibstyles))

Comment: This looks like a good start.  Wouldn't it be nice to have more that include letter classes, etc.?  A gallery of examples for the many CTAN packages would make selection a lot easier.

Comment: I think the bib styles are regular BibTeX styles, not `biblatex` styles.