# Technical documentation class

Tags: document-classes, documentation

I just made a component that is going to be added to our platform in the next month.
As such I need tu draw out some documentation for the guys that will do the integration.

Is there any class that allows me to quickly produce technical documentation or do I need do engineer it myself?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.se!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: can you give an example (say, a published book or a pdf file on the web) that shows the look of what you want?  not everyone has the same idea of what such documentation should look like.  (for example, the documentation for a latex package, e.g. `texdoc xspace`, looks different from a unix man page, looks different from a "whatever for dummies" book.  that's not saying that any of these examples are appropriate for what you're doing.)

Comment: Bouncing off of what @barbarabeeton has said, there is likely not an existing class that will be to your liking, depending on your needs.  Different companies have different in-house standards, and these vary *wildly* from place to place.  A good starting place would be to export an existing piece of documentation to PDF and then linking to it here (or, better yet, taking a screenshot and then uploading to SE's imgur account).

Answer (score 1):

The `hitec` document class is de­signed for use for technical doc­u­men­ta­tion.  It is based on the standard `article` class, but was designed to have a very different look. There are a MWE [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99707/11604).