# Specification of the Layout for Q-A Reference Cards (Flashcards, Visual Cards)

Tags: tables, positioning, margins, double-sided, printing

I'm relatively new to LaTeX and I've used Microsoft Word so far for virtually all work with documents. For college, to use own question-and-answer reference cards, I decided once to split a portrait page (odd) and its adjacent page (even) in four equal cells with a 4x4 table.

On the compound face side I have questions and on the flip side - the respective answers. The cells are aligned and properly ordered as if mirrored on the long side of the page.

The design of a cell is nothing fancy, just a three-cell table in every face-side cell with a header split in a wide and a narrow cells, while the flip side is an empty cell.

This has worked out well, so far. But now we've moved to Linux and I don't have Microsoft Word. And there's a presentation looming at which I wanted to hand out some of my refcards.

Since I have too little time to wade through the manuals, which I do want to do later on, I would like to ask for a few hints as to **what packages/classes and functions/methods I need to reproduce the layout for such a two-sided reference card** so I can look up what's necessary only.

I'm concerned most with the **specifications of a template**, as I would like to have to specify the layout once and just use--if possible--delimiters per refcard and face/flip side within the body of the document.

Other than this, when **printing**, I would like to have the same layout as before, i.e., four face-side questions with four mirrored flip-side answers--unless there is a better way to do the individual flipping while printing multiple refcards per sheet.

I'm an experienced programmer and have used the LaTeX-like notation in MS Word for mathematical formulae. So I'd appreciate a reference to some sources of a similar layout to I can see what I need to replicate just as much as direct answers.

As @Fran's accepted answer has brought my attention to the package called flashcards, a quick search gave me a list of the suitable packages/styles/document classes for such a purpose as visual cards (and another as well), obtainable at the [CTAN Catalog](http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/help/Catalogue/bytopic.html#exams) under "Exams."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be some like this?

> Page 1: [image: MWE1]
>
> Page 2: [image: MWE2]

Source code:

```
\documentclass[avery5371,frame]{flashcards}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\cardfrontstyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\cardfrontfoot{Chemistry}
\begin{flashcard}[Write it on the blackboard]{Reaction producing barium sulphate?}
\Large \ce{SO4^2- + Ba^2+ -> BaSO4 v}
\end{flashcard}

\cardfrontfoot{Humor}
\begin{flashcard}[Acronyms]{ASAP}
 {\large Act swiftly awesome pachyderm.} \\  
(Dr Seuss' story \emph{Horton Hears a Who})

\includegraphics[width=2cm]{HortonHearsAWhoBookCover.jpg}
\end{flashcard}

% source image on 
% http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b8/HortonHearsAWhoBookCover.jpg 

\begin{flashcard}[Question]{How many types of people understand binary code?}
There are 10 types: \\[2ex]Those who understand binary, \\and those who don't.
\end{flashcard}

\cardfrontfoot{\LaTeX{}}
\begin{flashcard}[Question]{How to make flashcards?\\[1ex]

\includegraphics[width=2cm]{Puzzled}}
\Large Type \texttt{texdoc flashcards} \color{red}  !!!
\end{flashcard}

% SVG image converted to PDF with inkscape, source on 
% http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/Puzzld.svg

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is awesome and even more than I had hoped for. Thank you so much! Is it this one http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/help/Catalogue/entries/flashcards.html? I'll add the relevant keywords to my question so your answer is easier for others to find.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, the class are in the package of the same name on http://www.ctan.org/pkg/flashcards. It is included in TeX Live as well as MiKTeX.