# Flashcards: Extra blank pages and text not vertically centered

Tags: vertical-alignment, landscape, blank-page

I am trying to make simple two sided flash cards of quotations with one side being the reference and the other side containing the quote. In order to print the cards, they need to be landscape. My code, however, is generating extra blank pages, and the text does not appear to be centered vertically on the page as intended.

**My questions:** What is causing the extra pages and how do I fix it? What adjustments do I need to make for the text to center vertically on the page?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[paperwidth=126mm, 
    paperheight=75mm,
    landscape,
    left=0.50in,
    right=0.50in,
    top=0.50in,
    bottom=0.50in]{geometry}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lscape}
\linespread{1.3}

\newcommand{\myref}[1]{
    \begin{landscape}
    \topskip0pt
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \centering\Huge{#1}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \end{landscape}
    \newpage
}

\newcommand{\myquote}[1]{
    \begin{landscape}
    \topskip0pt
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \justify\normalsize{#1}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \end{landscape}
}

\begin{document}

\myref{John 3:16}

\myquote{For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son,
that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting
life.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but .. Do you know the  `flashcard` document class? There are some examples  [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134150/11604) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152957/11604).

Comment: Thank you. I have looked at the `flashcard` class, but it seems more designed for flashcards of formulae and not for quotations.

Answer (score 2):

After more research I'll answer my own question for the benefit of the community.

The extra pages are caused by `\topskip0pt`. Change that to `\topskip=0.01pt` and the extra pages will magically go away, as per [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/kKlrEjd4bdg) explanation.

One simple way to center the text vertically is to change the left margin from `0.50in` to `0.30in` in addition to what is already there:

```
\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
Your text
\vspace*{\fill}
```

(The reason for changing the left margin is that the pages in the example are turned 90 degrees.)

I am sure that there is a better way to do this, but this works in a pinch.

Comment: Thanks. I've experienced the same issue. Setting `\topskip1sp` is sufficient.