# How do I make a Story Card with LaTex?

Tags: tcolorbox

```
\begin{document}
Anforderungsdokument\\
676421\\

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c } 
 \hline
Klassifikation & Priorität & Kategorie & Komplexität & Beschreibung\\ \hline
 funktionial & 10 & GUI & 2 & Erstellung von Benutzeroberfläche \\ 
 nicht-funktional & 10 & Testing & 1 &  Bestehen von Testcases \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}
blablabla\\
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{align}
StoryCard
\end{align}


\end{tcolorbox}
Hoaray
\end{document}
```

Now I came to the point to position them. How do I position and size things with tcolorbox?

I want to create Story Cards

Thanks for any help!

Solved : in case someone needs that in the future. Tell us how much bitcoin is worth haha

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=450pt, height=250pt]
    \begin{picture}(0,0) 
        \put(380,-40){
            \begin{tcolorbox}[width=50pt, height=50pt]
            Story Point
            \end{tcolorbox}}    
        \put(-20,-40){
            \begin{tcolorbox}[width=50pt, height=50pt]
            Prio
            \end{tcolorbox}} 
        \put(110,-40){
            \begin{tcolorbox}[width=200pt, height=50pt]
            Name der Story
            \end{tcolorbox}} 
        \put(-20,-240){
            \begin{tcolorbox}[width=50pt, height=50pt]
            Risiko
            \end{tcolorbox}} 
        \put(380,-240){
            \begin{tcolorbox}[width=50pt, height=50pt]
            Story Points
            \end{tcolorbox}} 
        \put(160,-240){
        Bottom Mid}
\end{picture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Not sure if this help, but maybe the `flashcards` class might interest you. There are some examples [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134150/11604) and [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152957/11604) in this site. Using the  tag [flashcards](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flashcards) you will see also another approaches to make cards.

Answer (score 2):

Upon your question the following came to my mind.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[
    factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=80
]{microtype}

\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, ducks, shadings}

\tcbset{
    sc outer box/.style = {
        fonttitle = \sffamily,
        fontupper = \small,
        size      = title,
        coltitle  = orange!15!white,
        top       = \smallskipamount,
        left      = 1mm,
        right     = 1mm,
        lefttitle = 1mm,
        parbox    = true,
        colframe  = orange!50!black,
        colback   = orange!20
    }
}

\newtcolorbox{scinnerbox}[1]{
    standard jigsaw,
    nobeforeafter,
    left        = 1mm,
    right       = 1mm,
    bottom      = 1mm,
    height      = 2.7cm,
    colframe    = orange!50!black,
    boxrule     = 0.7pt,
    opacityback = 0.3,
    width       = \linewidth,
    halign      = center,
    after       = {%
        \smallskip%
        \tcbsubtitle[
            sc outer box,
            boxrule   = 0.4pt,
            colback   = orange!70!black!30!white,
            colupper  = orange!50!black,
            fontupper = \vphantom{Äy},
            left      = 1mm
        ]{#1}\smallskip
    },
}

\newtcolorbox{scouterbox}[1]{
    nobeforeafter,
    sc outer box,
    skin           = widget,
    adjusted title = {#1},
    height         = 9cm,
    width          = 6cm,
    fontupper      = \sffamily,
    fontlower      = \sffamily,
    underlay       = {
        \fill[
            upper left  = yellow!50!orange!70!black,
            upper right = orange!60!white,
            lower left = orange!60!white,
            lower right = orange!60!white,
        ]( interior.south west) rectangle (interior.north east);
        \pattern[
            shade,
            pattern color = orange!80!black,
            fill opacity  = 0.45,
            pattern       = crosshatch dots
        ] (interior.south west) rectangle (interior.north east);
    },
}

\begin{document}

\centering
\foreach \i/\j in {1/{crazyhair},2/{longhair}} {
    \begin{scouterbox}{Story Card \i}    
        \begin{scinnerbox}{History of Duck No. \i}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw pic[scale=0.9, duck/\j] {duck};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{scinnerbox}
        \lipsum[1][1-6]
    \end{scouterbox}\hskip 1em
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks I have done it with tcolorbox and put now