# Compilation of LaTeX style files?

Tags: packages, templates, document-classes

I've just gone through every google search I can think of without success. Is there an archive, database, list, or other compilation of LaTeX style files? I've found plenty of style files specific to certain journals or conferences, but are there any 'generic' themes out there? I'd like to make my document look a little different from whatever the out-of-the-box LaTex default, and more than just changing the font...

I'm no pro, and don't have the expertise, time, or motivation to write my own style file. Also, I assume there are plenty of style files out there, analagous to the different 'Themes' or 'templates' used by microsoft products. Ideally there would be an image/example so that i could see what the style made the document look like.

Where are they?

Comment: `amsart` for papers! Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/782/14757

Comment: @Sigur, your comment is a perfect example of the sort of thing google turns up...if i was looking for an ams style file, i would have no problem finding that particular one... but i'm looking for a more generic list of style files, with examples.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that you search for packages or template files, which provide a style, or let’s call it a theme, for a document? The term “style files” is very, very slightly ambiguously in context of LaTeX …

Comment: Are you looking for http://ctan.org/? Or are you looking for more specific suggestions such as http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir? There are an enormous number of style files out there. As Speravir says, your question is also ambiguous in this context. I'm not sure whether you are looking for class files rather than what LaTeX calls style files. .sty typically "theme" particular aspects of a document or enable you to do so easily. .cls files control the basic overall "theme" of the document. (Very, very roughly. Usually.) What sort of documents do you produce?

Comment: What are you going to write?  Scholarly articles, professional letters, textbooks, etc., all require very different 'styles', but then within each genre there is plenty of room for variety.  There is also a website called 'latex templates', I think.  And of course ConTeXt is great for *not* looking like generic LaTeX (unless you want it to).

Comment: I'm writing a large report, which will be based on my PhD thesis.  A large amount of the content will simply be cut/pasted into the report - but right now i'm working with my university's thesis class, and wanted to make the report at least look different. I don't have a specific wish list of features, i'd just like to browse through a bunch of templates, as I can with microsoft word or powerpoint. Searching ctan.org for 'style' or 'template' or 'example' doesn't get me close to this.

Comment: @Speravir, yes - i'm looking for a compilation of different themes. Maybe they're latex classes, styles, macros, i'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like jon said in the comments, there is: http://www.latextemplates.com/

That will provide you with quite some templates that are different from the default, and also in a wide range of document types: from book to CV, thesis to calendar, essay to presentation.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for; though it only provides 3-4 examples for each category of document. I imagine there are dozens if not hundreds of different examples of the 'article' class out there, and this site has only 3.