# Front page problems

Tags: titles

I have made a front page that I thought was a A3 page (so i could put in the rest of the document of A4 pages) and make something like a book (hope that I am understood). When I tried to print the front page I saw that the page output was A4, so there was cuts to fit into the page. Here's my code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 

\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{ {/home/Petros/images/} }

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[papersize={,10.5in},spine=1in,cropmarks,textwidth=7in,leftmargin=0in,nopagenumbers,color]{zwpagelayout}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[counterclockwise]{rotating}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\hbox to \textwidth{%
  \vbox to \textheight{\hsize \UserWidth \centering


\
\
\  
\pagecolor{gray}
\color{white}
\textbf{Μελέτη της επίδρασης των ρυθμιστικών \\ διαλυμάτων  φωσφορικών και καρβοξυλικών ιόντων στην απελευθέρωση  \\ μονομερών από συνθετικές ρητίνες}

\
\
\
\
\par{Η παρούσα ερευνητική μελέτη ασχολείται με την επίδραση που έχουν τα 
ιόντα που βρίσκονται φυσιολογικά στο σάλιο στις συνθετικές ρητίνες που 
χρησιμοποιούνται στην οδοντιατρική ως επανορθωτικά αποκαταστατικά 
υλικά. Ο ρόλος του σάλιου είναι πολύπλοκος γιατί μπορεί έμμεσα να 
προκαλεί διαβρωτικά φαινόμενα αλλά και να δράσει προστατευτικά. Σε 
παλαιότερες εργασίες η μελέτη της συμπεριφοράς άλλων 
εμφρακτικών υλικών όπως το αμάλγαμα, σε 
παρόμοιες συνθήκες φύλαξης, είχε ως αποτέλεσμα 
τη δημιουργία ενός σταθερού ημιδιαφανούς υμενίου
στην επιφάνεια των 
δειγμάτων. Αυτό το υμένιο εμπόδιζε την περαιτέρω οξείδωση των
δειγμάτων. Ο προστατευτικός του ρόλος μπορεί αποτέλεσμα διαφόρων υμενίων ή
ιζημάτων που δημιουργούνται στην επιφάνεια των αποκαταστατικών υλικών 
από συνθετική ρητίνη ως αποτέλεσμα των αντιδράσεων των απελευθερούμενων 
μονομερών και των ιόντων του σάλιου.}
\par{Οι συνθετικές ρητίνες που χρησιμοποιούνται για την αποκατάσταση στην αρχική φυσιολογική κατάσταση των τερηδονισμένων ή σπασμένων δοντιών αποτελούν υλικά που έχουν εξελιχθεί να διαθέτουν πολύ καλές χημικομηχανικές ιδιότητες. Οι ιδιότητες αυτές πλησιάζουν για διάφορα υλικά τις μηχανικές ιδιότητες της αδαμαντίνης και της οδοντίνης. Παρόλα αυτά όμως η φυσιολογία των ιστών αυτών μπορεί να είναι σχετικά εύκολο να μιμηθούν από πλευράς μηχανικών ιδιοτήτων αλλά η χημικές ιδιότητες των συνθετικών ρητινών έχουν διάφορα μειονεκτήματα και συνοδεύονται από διάφορες ανεπιθύμητες ενέργειες. Μία από αυτές είναι η τοξικότητα, ή διάφορες αλλεργικές αντιδράσεις με περιστατικά να έχουν δημοσιευθεί στην διεθνή οδοντιατρική βιβλιογραφία.}
\par{Αυτές οι ανεπιθύμητες ενέργειες οφείλονται κατά κύριο λόγο στην απελευθέρωση ουσιών από τις οποίες αποτελούνται οι συνθετικές ρητίνες. Οι ουσίες που απελευθερώνονται είναι τα μονομερή και είναι συνήθως τα \selectlanguage{english}{BisGMA, UDMA, TEGDMA}, \selectlanguage{greek} ενώ υπάρχουν ερευνητικές μελέτες που κατέγραψαν και την παρουσία της δισ-φαινόλης Α \selectlanguage{english}{(BPA)} \selectlanguage{greek} στις ουσίες απελευθέρωσης των συνθετικών ρητινών.}
\par{Σκοπός της ερευνητικής αυτής μελέτης είναι να μελετήσει την
επίδρασης των ρυθμιστικών διαλυμάτων φωσφορικών και διττανθρακικών 
ιόντων που περιέχονται στο σάλιο σε σχέση με την απελευθέρωση μονομερών 
από συνθετικές ρητίνες.}



\color{white}
}\hss
  \vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropSpine \centering \color{white}
        \begin{sideways}\fontsize{16}{16}\selectfont \textbf{Αριστοτέλειο Πανεπιστήμιο Θεσσαλονίκης\hspace{1in} Πέτρος Μουρούζης $2015$}\end{sideways}
        \\[2em] 
        }\hss
  \vbox to \textheight{\hsize \UserWidth \centering
\begin{center}
\color{white}

\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    \vspace*{\baselineskip}
    \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\\[\baselineskip]
    {\LARGE H επίδραση των ρυθμιστικών διαλυμάτων \\ φωσφορικών και καρβοξυλικών ιόντων στην απελευθέρωση  \\[0.3\baselineskip] μονομερών από συνθετικές ρητίνες}\\[0.2\baselineskip]
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\\[\baselineskip]
    \scshape
    Αριστοτέλειο Πανεπιστήμιο Θεσσαλονίκης\\Εργαστήριο Βασικών Οδοντιατρικών Επιστημών \\
    Τομέας Παθολογίας και Θεραπευτικής των Οδοντικών Ιστών \\
     \par
    \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
    Διδακτορική Διατριβή \\[\baselineskip]
    {\Large Πέτρος Μουρούζης \\ Οδοντίατρος \\ \par}
    {\itshape Αριστοτέλειο Πανεπιστήμιο Θεσσαλονίκης \\ \par}
    \vfill
    {\scshape ΘΕΣΣΑΛΟΝΙΚΗ} \\
    {\large 5 Δεκεμβρίου 2015}\par


\end{titlepage}

\end{center}
}\hss}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [What are the available "documentclass" types and their uses?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231971)

Comment: @Johannes_B Can you expand on why that may help?

Comment: @AndrewSwann To me, that question of how to create a title in A3 to be used with an A4 document, sounds like the OP is looking for a dustcover. Hence the link to the `bookcover`class. The automatic conversion of links is a bit misleading here, i have to say.