# Universal Default Themes of Linux Latex Installation?

Tags: themes

There is a good way to install Latex to avoid many junk of libraries under Linux:

```
apt-get install --no-install-recommends texlive
apt-get install --no-install-recommends beamer
```

With this method, it can run well on any Linux machines, even on a low power raspberry PI. With this installation method, you can be sure that your book editors or manuscript publishers will not complain of not being capable to make a PDF out of your source file.

In beamer there is a lot of default theme with this minimal installation method.

However, I searched into the directory /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex, but it seems that there aren't default themes for Latex, for instance reports, articles,...

It is actually good, yeah, because we asked for a minimal installation.

I am expecting that I could have maybe not found if there are few beautiful latex default themes, for articles, books,... that are in all Linux distros for sure.

Thank you

Comment: what is the question exactly?

Comment: if there exists some templates for reports, ... by default, as for beamer.

Comment: I guess you mean [document classes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/782/3323)? If so, have a look at the `.cls` files in the [file list of the `texlive-latex-recommended`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/all/texlive-latex-recommended/filelist) package (which is a dependency of `texlive`): it includes two of the most common document classes other than the standard ones (`article`, `report`, ...) found in every LaTeX installation, namely the [KOMA-Script](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes and [`memoir`](https://ctan.org/pkg/memoir).